# Roll Dungeons and Dragons dice

Tags: code-golf, random

I want to play Dungeons and Dragons, but I don't have any dice! Your challenge is to roll some D&D dice.

The input format specification in [Backus-Naur form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) is:

```
<valid-input>  ::= <opt-integer> "d" <integer> <opt-modifier>
<opt-integer>  ::= | <integer>
<opt-modifier> ::= | "+" <integer>
<integer>      ::= "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" |
                   "6" | "7" | "8" | "9" | <integer> <integer>
```

The optional integer before the `d` is the number of dice to roll; it must be at least `1`, and defaults to `1` if not supplied.

The required integer immediately after the `d` is the number of sides each die has; it must be at least `1`. The sides of each die are distinct consecutive positive integers starting at `1`.

The optional modifier may be `+0`, and it defaults to `+0` if not specified.

For example, for the input `2d10+5`, you generate two random numbers from 1 to 10 inclusive, add them together, and add 5. Then you will output the result.

If you receive invalid input, such as `2d`, `d20+`, `0d4`, `2d5+1+2`, `2+2`, or anything else that doesn't fit this format, you must output "`Invalid input`". Otherwise, you must output only a single random integer, weighted according to the input. For example, [`3d6` should produce more `10`s than `4`s](http://anydice.com/program/1/).

#### Test cases

```
Input      Minimum possible output    Maximum possible output
d1         1                          1
d6         1                          6
d1+3       4                          4
d20+3      4                          23
2d1        2                          2
2d6+2      4                          14
d01        1                          1
d01+0      1                          1
01d01+01   2                          2
3d20+10    13                         70

d          Invalid input
d0         Invalid input
d+0        Invalid input
d0+0       Invalid input
0d1        Invalid input
0d1+1      Invalid input
d1+        Invalid input
1d         Invalid input
1d1+       Invalid input
1d+1       Invalid input
2d+2d      Invalid input
d2+d2      Invalid input
d2+2+2     Invalid input
d2-1       Invalid input
-d2        Invalid input
-2d2       Invalid input
4*3        Invalid input
4*d2       Invalid input
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes will win!

Comment: Is `2d10-5` a valid input? -- Oops, I missed the part where you said p is 0 or more. Nevermind.

Comment: Is `02d05+073` a valid input?

Comment: Can you throw a 13 sided die? Or a 17 sided die?

Comment: The hard part about this question is validating the input, but the paragraph which describes the validation rules is self-contradictory. It describes `n` and `p` as optional, but input which choose not to include them (`d20+`) as invalid.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I think the `+` sign should only be added if the modifier `p` is provided.

Comment: @MT0 Yes; `02` is a number >= 1.

Comment: @Averroes Of course, why not?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Edited post to clarify ("...and preceded by a `+` sign.")

Comment: @Doorknob, Well, because d13 and d17 aren't dice used in D&D. D&D uses d4, d6, d8, d10, d12, and d20. Also, there are certainly cases where a roll would include different types of dice (eg, `1d4+1d6` for a Rogue sneak attacking with a dagger) or having a negative `p` (eg, `1d20-1` for a skill check with no ranks/training and a negative ability modifier).

Comment: @BrianS well you also sometimes see the odd `d3` which is done using a normal die and dividing by 2 (rounding up). I'm not entirely sure but I may have seen `d2` as well which is just flipping a coin (or using a similar method as above). But yes `d13` and `d17` are a bit unusual.

Comment: @m.buettner, I think 3.5/PF might use d2/d3 for whips, but the standard is to simulate those with d4/d6 (particularly when considering a "standard set" available at hobby shops). 4e doesn't have dice below d4, although it does have things like Weakened condition/half damage.

Comment: You're going to play dnd without the usecase of `2d8 + 1d6 + 4`? You're gonna have a bad time

Comment: `2d6+2      4                          12` is wrong; max should be 14.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman, concur. Fixed.

Comment: Similar to [Halloween Golf: The 2spooky4me Challenge!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62350/) and the [Universal Spooky Meme Translator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79809/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Perl, <s>109</s> <s>95</s> <s>93</s> <s>96</s> 89 bytes

```
s/^d/1d/;/^(\d+)d(\d+)(\+\d+)?$/;$d+=1+rand$2|0for
1..$1;$_=$1*$2?$d+$3:'Invalid input'
```

Requires the `-p` switch, which accounts for two of the bytes. Try it online on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/gLJfhO).

#### How it works

- Because of the `-p` switch, a line is read from STDIN and stored in `$_`.
- The command `s/^d/1d/` prepends a *1* to `$_` if it begins with a *d*, i. e., if the number of dice has not been specified.
- The regular expression `/^(\d+)d(\d+)(\+\d+)?/` checks if the line consists of a number, a literal *d*, another number and, optionally, a third number preceded by a *+* sign.

  If there is a match, the numbers will be saved in `$1`, `$2` and `$3`.

  In this case, the input will be valid if and only if `$1` and `$2` are both positive.
- `$d += 1 + rand $2 | 0` adds a pseudo-randomly chosen integer from 1 to the specified number of sides to `$d` (initially treated as zero).
- `for 1 .. $1` does the above once for every integer between 1 and the number of dice.
- The command `$_ = $1 * $2 ? $d + $3 : 'Invalid input'` does the following:

  - If `$1 * $2` is zero, it sets `$_` to *Invalid input*.
  - Otherwise, the input is valid and it sets `$_` to the sum of the dice rolls and the modifier.
- Because of the `-p` switch, Perl prints the contents of `$_`.
- Since there a no further input lines, the script exits.

Comment: I believe that, in general, extra command line parameters are considered to be worth a byte each but the hyphen is free. In this case, `-p` would only cost you one, making this a 108 byte solution.

Comment: You can use `1..$1||1` instead of `1..$1?$1:1`, 2 chars shorter

Comment: Can be made 96 chars, `/^([1-9]\d*)?d([1-9]\d*)(\+\d+)?$/||die"Invalid input$/";$a+=1+int rand$2for(1..$1||1);$_=$a+$3`

Comment: @undergroundmonorail: I've seen people counting a single command-line switch as one, two and even three (counting the whitespace) bytes. I'd rather count it as one, but two bytes seems fair to me.

Comment: @Hasturkun: Thanks. Parentheses and curly brackets... Not sure what I was thinking. This is Perl!

Comment: Your count is too high: the current program is only 87 chars. I assume you've counted a Windows newline and an EOF.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I've counted the `-p` switch as two bytes.

Comment: I assume you haven't tested this.  |0 is not the same as ||0.

Comment: @Vynce I assume you haven't either. I use `|0` to cast to int, since `rand` returns a pseudo-randomly chosen *float*.

Comment: Actually, you're right -- but for the wrong reason. ( : I noticed that rand gave floats, and was trying to test the program, and was wondering how you were getting around it; i'm trying to run it and getting lots of syntax errors on the command line.

ETA: ah.  I'm used to perl golfing a -e and this has to be actually a file to work as written

Comment: @Vynce I've added a permalink to the question (http://ideone.com/gLJfhO). `-e` would be problematic here, unless you replace the single quotes with double quotes.

Answer (score 6):

## Fortran: 145

```
character(1)a;read(*,*)s,a,j,a,k;n=0;if(k<0.or.a=="-")then;print*,"error k<0";stop;endif;do l=1,int(s);n=n+int(s*rand(0)+1);enddo;print*,n+k;end;
```

Abuses implicit typing (`i-n` are all integers, everything else a real). Minor caveat: input must be space separated, so `2d10+5` must be entered as `2 d 10 + 5`, otherwise you'll get an `input conversion error`.

Comment: The basic logic is cool, but this does not handle `d 1` correctly (nor several other inputs), nor is the output random. Also no need for `;` at the end. [Examples](https://tio.run/##Nc1BDoMgEAXQPacgrADRgKYrymGIQLU2YEbuT4HaxSRvfn5mQoIMNo6v8EMp62bBrtkDVcxq8NZRLji7hBXvOgeKRuo90OMppwSTNYaMhOXNR33CHjMXxAMkwLVA9JXTqX10e0Au4Y9RolboxXQ0cejk9aujkg2KtaJL6D4ThwPVoJQFOzxLPGAlkfp76VRdc9O9o8YetNbjCw)

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby, 116

Alternative Ruby version.  I was trying to find a way to do it without the regular expressions, but the validation you have to do is a lot harder without them.

```ruby
gets=~/^(\d+)?d(\d+)(\+\d+)?$/
a=$1||?1
puts$~&&a>?0?eval("r=#{$3||0};#{a}.times{r+=rand(#$2)+1};r"):'Invalid input'
```

This one is 112, using Dennis' clever Perl algorithm:

```ruby
$p='(\d*[1-9]\d*)'
puts~/^#$p?d#$p(\+\d+)?$/?eval("r=#{$3||0};#{$1||1}.times{r+=rand(#$2)+1};r"):'Invalid input'
```

Comment: @m.buettner Thanks!  I don't know why I thought it had to be >0.

Answer (score 3):

### GolfScript (<strike>120</strike> 106 bytes)

```
.100?!1`*\+.43?)!'+0'*+.10,'d+':^*-!*.10,''*-^=*^1/{/n*}/~].,3=*3,or:x~;*{x~\{rand)+}+@*}'Invalid input'if
```

This is not only shorter than the first version, but also more elegant. The part which actually does the die rolling is

```
\{rand)+}+@*
```

The rest is mainly input validation, and a few characters for parsing.

```
# Start by converting valid inputs into valid inputs with all optional bits.
# Prepend a '1' if the string starts with 'd'.
.100?!1`*\+
# Append '+0' if there's no '+' in the string.
.43?)!'+0'*+
# Now we start knocking out the invalid inputs.
# If it contains a character other than [0-9d+], replace the string with ''.
.10,'d+':^*-!*
# If it doesn't contain exactly one 'd', exactly one '+', and the 'd' before the '+',
# replace the string with ''.
.10,''*-^=*
# Now we either have a valid string, an empty string, or a string which is almost valid
# but has some empty substrings which should be integers, or a forbidden 0 integer value.
# Replace the 'd' and '+' with newlines, eval the result, and gather into an array.
^1/{/n*}/~]
# If we had any empty parts, we'll have fewer than 3 items on the stack.
# In that case, replace with integer values which will fail the final validation step.
.,3=*3,or
# Final validation: number of dice * number of sides per die != 0.
:x~;*
# If we pass, do the actual die rolling. Otherwise give the error message.
{x~\{rand)+}+@*}'Invalid input'if
```

[Online demo with test framework](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IyMKOydkMQpkNgpkMSszCmQyMCszCjJkMQoyZDYrMgpkMDEKZDAxKzAKMDFkMDErMDEKM2QyMCsxMApkCmQwCmQrMApkMCswCjBkMQowZDErMQpkMSsKMWQKMWQxKwoxZCsxCjJkKzJkCmQyK2QyCmQyKzIrMgpkMi0xCi1kMgotMmQyCjQqMwo0KmQyCiduL3sKLnAKIyMKCi4xMDA%2FITFgKlwrLjQzPykhJyswJyorLjEwLCdkKyc6XiotISouMTAsJycqLV49Kl4xL3svbip9L35dLiwzPSozLG9yOnh%2BOyp7eH5ce3JhbmQpK30rQCp9J0ludmFsaWQgaW5wdXQnaWYKCiMjCnByaW50IG4gcHJpbnR9LwojIwo%3D)

Comment: I'm wondering why you don't use `n./`? Maybe also `10,n*` for one character less.

Comment: @Howard, to the first, because it was a last minute hack to pass some test cases and I didn't think about golfing it. To the second, that would make it accept some invalid input.

Answer (score 2):

## J - 130 (45?) char

This challenge seems to be a little biased towards regular expressions, especially with having to differentiate invalid input. J has a POSIX regex library, so it's not that bad, but it's not integrated as it is with Perl, so J fares no better than other languages.

```
+/@,`(1+?@#~)/`('Invalid input'"_)@.(0 e.$)0 1 1>.".>|.}.((,'?d','(\+[0-9]+)?$',~}.)'^([0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)')(rxmatch rxfrom])1!:1]1
```

If you're just implementing the logic for valid expressions, like the Python/PHP solutions appear to, it's the more reasonable 45 chars:

```
+/,(1+[:?@#/1>.".;._2@,&'d')`".;._1'+',1!:1]1
```

Notable bits:

- `1!:1]1` is the input, and `(rxmatch rxfrom])` is the logic that returns the subexpression matches.
- Whether or not the input was legal is handled by the regex matching, so we can set the defaults for n and p with `0 1 1>.`. It looks backwards (n is 1 by default and p is 0) because we had to reverse (`|.`) the list earlier, so that the logic at the end executes in the right order.
- `@.` is the *Agenda* conjunction, essentially a J-ish switch statement. If the matches are empty (if 0 is an e.lement of the $hape: `0 e.$`), we emit the error message, else we go through with rolling the dice: `#~` to set out the dice, `1+?` to roll, and `+/@,` to add the modifier p and sum.

Comment: Does that work for `01d01+01`?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman My bad. It does now.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 378

Just wanted to try a solution with Java far from the best solution. But hey: Java isn't a golfing language in any case!

It gets the input from command line. First parameter `args[0]` is the input value.

```java
class A{public static void main(String[]s){System.out.print(s[0].matches(
"(0+\\d+|[1-9]\\d*|)d(0+\\d+|[1-9]\\d*)(\\+\\d+)?")?z(s[0]):"Invalid input");}static int
z(String s){String[]a=s.split("d");String[]b=a[1].split("\\+");int c=a[0].isEmpty()?1:Byte.
decode(a[0]);int d=b.length<2?0:Byte.decode(b[1]);while(c-->0)d+=new java.util.Random().
nextInt(Byte.decode(b[0]))+1;return d;}}
```

Did you know, that `decode` is shorter than `valueOf`?

Answer (score 2):

### [TinyMUSH](http://www.tinymush.net/index.php/Main_Page), 239

```
@dig/t +
@op d=+
@lo d=d
@fail d=Invalid input
@cr .
@set .=com
&d .=$*:\ifelse(regmatch(%0,^(\\\\d+)?d(\\\\d+)(\\\\+\\\\d+)?$,0 1 2 3),ifzero(and(or(not(strlen(%q1)),%q1),%q2),Invalid input,add(die(usetrue(%q1,1),%q2),%q3)),Invalid input)
```

The first four lines deal with the fact that "d" is an alias for the universal "down" exit with a built-in failure message when it doesn't exist; exits are scanned before user-defined commands.  The remaining lines create an object with a user-defined command making use of the built-in die() function.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 129

```
<?eval(preg_filter(~Ð¡×£›ÔÖÀ›×£›Ö×£Ô£›ÔÖÀÛÐ,~ÛžÂÝÛÎÝÀÅÎÄ™×ÄÛ–ÔÔÃÛžÄÛŒÔÂž‘›×ÎÓÛÍÖÖÄšœ—ÛŒÛÌÄ,$_GET[0])?:~šœ—Ý¶‘‰ž“–›ß–‘Š‹ÝÄ);
```

Uses a regex to create a expression which PHP then evaluates.
Input is fed in via url: ?0=*argument*. Make sure you urlencode the + to %2b.
Here's what it looks like in a more readable form:

```
eval(preg_filter('/^(\\d)?d(\\d)(\\+\\d)?$/','$a="$1"?:1;for(;$i++<$a;$s+=rand(1,$2));echo$s$3;',$_GET[0])?:'echo"Invalid input";');
```

Bitwise inverting the strings using `~` not only saves a character because you don't need quotes (PHP assumes they are strings) but also saves characters because you don't have to escape the backslashes in the regular expression.

The `?:` operator is a special form of the ternary operator. `$foo = $a ? $a : $b` is the same as `$foo = $a ?: $b`.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>167</s> 147

```
/^(\d+)?d(\d+)(\+\d+)?$/.match gets
abort'Invalid input'if !$~||$1==?0||!$2||$2==?0
p eval(([0]*($1||1).to_i).map{rand($2.to_i)+1}*?+)+($3||0).to_i
```

Uses a regexp to do all the work. Since I'm using `\d+`, the only things I need to check for invalid input are that there was a match, that neither `n` nor `m` were `0`, and that there was an `m`. If any of those are found, it aborts with a message (`'Invalid input'`). Then it just prints the result, since it would have aborted by now if the input was invalid.

The result-printing isn't that interesting, but...

```
([0]*($1||1).to_i)    # create an array of n elements (1 if there is no n)
.map{rand($2.to_i)+1} # fill it up with random numbers, where the number x is 1 < x < m+1
.inject(:+)           # add them all up
+($3||0).to_i         # and finally add the modifier (0 if there is none)
```

I later changed `.inject(:+)` to `eval(...*?+)`, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 184 bytes

```py
import random,re
try:a,b,c=re.findall("^(\d*)d(\d+)(\+\d+)?$",input())[0];t=int(c or 0)+(sum(random.randint(1,int(b))for i in range(int(a or 1)))or q)
except:t="Invalid input"
print(t)
```

Passes all tests. If zero dice were allowed, it would be 6 bytes shorter by leaving out `(or q)`.

Comment: I misunderstood the BNF, though. [This page](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/what-is-bnf-and-why-should-developers-care/) helps.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else who wonders why the regex is anchored at one end but not the other: Python's `re.match` implicitly anchors at the start but not at the end. I'm not aware of any other regex library which does that.

Comment: There's a small saving by initialising `t=int(c or 0)`; and it might be possible to combine your answer with the existing Python one (which uses less whitespace) to save a couple more.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `V`, 89 bytes

```
h\d=[1p|]⁽±Ḋ→a⟨←aL5=|←a⌊±T⟨0|2|4⟩=|←a1i\d=|←a3i\+=⟩A[←a0i⌊ʁ(←a2i⌊℅⅛)¾∑←a4i⌊+,|«¢q⁰∷Ṗ-←¥«,
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQViIsIiIsImhcXGQ9WzFwfF3igb3CseG4iuKGkmHin6jihpBhTDU9fOKGkGHijIrCsVTin6gwfDJ8NOKfqT184oaQYTFpXFxkPXzihpBhM2lcXCs94p+pQVvihpBhMGnijIrKgSjihpBhMmnijIrihIXihZspwr7iiJHihpBhNGnijIorLHzCq8KiceKBsOKIt+G5li3ihpDCpcKrLCIsIiIsIjJkNSsxMiJd)

Ties Perl

````
h\d=[1p|]         # Checks if the first character is a d, and prepends a 1 
        ⁽±Ḋ→a     # Splits the string on non-numeric values, so consecutive digits stay grouped, then casts the list to variable "a"

     ⟨←aL5=|           # is it Length 5 (3 numbers, the "+" and the "d")
       ←a⌊±T⟨0|2|4⟩=|  # convert the numbers-as-strings to numbers and check if the numbers are in positions 1 3 and 5 (0 indexed)
         ←a1i\d=|     # is the second item in the list  "d"
           ←a3i\+=⟩    # is the fourth item "+"
                A     # are all of these checks true?

  [←a0i⌊ʁ               # If all the checks are true, create a range from 0-a[0]
        (←a2i⌊℅⅛)       #  for i in said range, generate a random number 0-a[2] and push to global array
             ¾∑←a4i⌊+,  # push global array, sum the values, and add a[4] 

            |«¢q⁰∷Ṗ-←¥«, # If any of the checks are false, print "invalid input"
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## Zsh, 205 <s>223</s> bytes

```ps
set -e;e=Invalid\ input;trap '<<<$e' ERR
echo "^0d\n+$\nd+\n+d\n+.+\n[-|*]">p;[[ `grep -cfp<<<$1`>0 ]]&&<<<$e&&exit
q=(${(s: :)${1//(#s)d/1d}//[^0-9]/ });for i ({1..$q[1]})((s+=RANDOM%q[2]+1))
<<<$[s+q[3]]
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##TY9fa8IwFMXf8yku2tnGUJukQ5i1wmB72MM28DVGdCbVgvSP7caY87O7JplzCdzz495zbshXszs3ui2rFvRnqwul1XZfviGUBThATUpRX292JfQ81jNGCHWi06fiY73P1QLyonpvk/awrsCfTqee9uFxPkcusqRqURBvUSjSqeFRByL8HsrerEqEgNX2oCsIN1llwmw1oyDlYGA3DQb6M29RnQbeMWgmMMHekUVR0G@wipg6RZFY0vBORnDCSVYeIIfgyEYjrxZMnnAQNCSd3788vD7f1IJLwjBGZrFoSC1iKc8YZaCYKWNLJDbCqVU2tl1uDVyNCTdDylwltFPKLDHoODY5Ru3HjcXaTLFORV3ALusqYWCOe/WXmPqDf72rkyvClctwojhcsLsXDpmj0I4dcscd@rfD2L@y4v75Bw) (with all test cases)

Writing the validation code was a chore. Without this guff, the solution would be a [svelte 89 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYuxCsIwFEX3fEVoIyQEm7wUCpZ2EFxVcA1x0KRWEGtNB7H022Mbl3sO97379W3wbuheA3afwT2ts7dHd0GooYwiX0uUumvb4YRAEvqakpH6EpeMjCAETT2zAuwkhD7L9cYIPDHUdG98x3SELCO9BjMxSj2vT9vD7rhf9VoZDoyhqqqI9rzXuTFhXmELSxTReL5AyUgoYqvig7IFV8tRwj@5nCkhGuDZ82UHMvwA):

```ps
q=(${(s: :)${1//(#s)d/1d}//[^0-9]/ });for i ({1..$q[1]})((s+=RANDOM%q[2]+1))
<<<$[s+q[3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 204B

Mine beats the existing Python answer by adding in the required error handling and reading `d20` as `1d20` rather than `0d20` :)

```
import random,re
try:a,b,c=re.findall('^([1-9]\d*)?d(\d+)(\+\d+)?$',input())[0];I=int;R=sum(random.randrange(I(b))+1for x in[0]*(1if a==''else I(a)))+(0if c==''else I(c))
except:R='Invalid input'
print(R)
```

edited to fix 2 typos: `I(x) => I(c)`, `Invalid Input => Invalid input`

edited to fix regex: `\+?(\d*) => (\+\d+)?`

Comment: According to the clarified question, this is an incorrect answer because it accepts the input `3d20+`.

Comment: Good point! #filler

Comment: And not `01d01+01`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), unseeded, 366 bytes

```go
import(."regexp";."strconv";."math/rand")
func f(s string)int{k:=MustCompile(`^(\d*)d(\d+)(\+\d+)?$`).FindAllStringSubmatch(s,-1)
if len(k)<1||k[0][2]==""{return-1}
r:=k[0]
var n,l,f,m,t int
l=len(r)
n,_=Atoi(r[1])
if n<1&&r[1]==""{n=1}else if n<1{return-1}
if l>2{f,_=Atoi(r[2])}
if f<1{return-1}
if l>3{m,_=Atoi(r[3])}
for i:=0;i<n;i++{t+=Intn(f)+1}
t+=m
return t}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVLdatswFGa3egohRidVdmbJo4wk3iiDwS42CmFXqdd6kZyK2HKQ5bTg5kl2Ewp7qO1ppp_-jK0339H50Xc-naMfd-vu8OvVtlptqrWEbaU0UO22M3aC6taiR8eqVqKfg63Tt79f6BjFE2TkWt5s0WyCemtWnd75Y1vZq9em0gIRUA96BWvcQ5dXek2UtuNmWnweevuha7eqkfjyGz4Xx0Q4pASfU2_ev7wkk49Ki9OmWYSbi-G7411d4T5JGQGqho3UeEPm7PZ2s8zKJS-LAqHRSDsYnbI9MNPCJ8CuMlAnTVInbWKhEwCawt81BOjkoji1ncJmycpAqufs6Mh7gUwXbC-bXsKY-Yvc93_Hx_qJgJckhOv_6_KxfarLfV3dGaimRTZTcz1TlI6WFp-01bgm1N1yXgsiCbT7h7G3YZh-R5jAESykFPhLd43J5KtWN5gQ4Ibcw2kBl2Uc94gEQwkSJx4Yzb3hWbA8ZLg4odxHMxaRZs5mLJx8KPf1LENR8kUS6N1u3WcJzUZw5hrZRru9-D07EfvHkJuo3lWNEv9oCq08hG4ii02DIIeURbUOmQhwf6ZRMeWBgFPBo-XxCTz1-TREUx7Mm-M8oHOeecCDuGffcD_1wyHaPw)

## [Go](https://go.dev), seeded, 393 bytes

```go
import(."regexp";."strconv";."math/rand";."time")
func f(s string)int{k:=MustCompile(`^(\d*)d(\d+)(\+\d+)?$`).FindAllStringSubmatch(s,-1)
if len(k)<1||k[0][2]==""{return-1}
r:=k[0]
var n,l,f,m,t int
l=len(r)
n,_=Atoi(r[1])
if n<1&&r[1]==""{n=1}else if n<1{return-1}
if l>2{f,_=Atoi(r[2])}
if f<1{return-1}
if l>3{m,_=Atoi(r[3])}
Seed(Now().Unix())
for i:=0;i<n;i++{t+=Intn(f)+1}
t+=m
return t}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVJbbtQwFBW_WYVlocqukxA7qEIzE1CFhMQHCGnED9PQhrEztSZxRo4zrZRmAayhP6NKLIKtsBr8aCmC_pzj-8i5r9zebbrDz1213lYbAdpKqki2u06bFNatgT8GUyevfj37HpwohVpsxPUOzlPYG73u1N4928pcvtCV4s4wshUQR_Wg1qBGPbB5Um2wVGbczooPQ2_edu1ONgJdfEVn_BhziwSjM-LozfMLnL6Tip82zdJ_uRy-Wf31JerjhOJI1qARCm3xgt7cbFdZuWJlUUA4amEGrRI6RXpWuEC0rzRQcRPXcRsbYBuImsJ9q3Gk4vPi1HQS6RUtvaha0KMjZ3kxVdBJNL0AIfKXuKv_mo31owArsXfX_-flY_uYl7u8pRAcfeyuEE4_K3mNsN1Up4GcFdlcLtRcEjIaUrxXRqEaEytkrTYKusBMDxf54vfrDoYwGCO75B7MCrAqw7pHyCmMIT9xQEnuiGWemY8wfkKY82Y0IMksZ9S_nCt3-TSDk-_vPPby9sb2N_HFxuiTLWQaZe_i7mwHmf647EbVvmok_6cnX8qBr8azUNQ3ZJHQ0K1Fyj3cv0nomDAvwAhngVkYgSUunnhvwjy9PM49WuOJAR6ae3KG-xUfDoF_Aw)