# Halloween Golf: The 2spooky4me Challenge!

Tags: code-golf, string

A current internet meme is to type 2spooky4me, with a second person typing 3spooky5me, following the `(n)spooky(n+2)me` pattern.

Your mission is to implement this pattern in your chosen language. You should write a program or function that takes a value `n` (from standard input, as a function argument, or closest alternative), and outputs the string `(n)spooky(n+2)me` (without the parentheses; to standard output, as a return value for a function, or closest alternative).

Your solution should work for all inputs, from `1` up to 2 below your language's maximum representable integer value (`2^32-3` for C on a 32-bit machine, for example).

Example implementation in Python:

```python
def spooky(n):
    return "%dspooky%dme"%(n,n+2)
```

`spooky(2) -> "2spooky4me"`

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden, and the shortest answer in bytes wins!

## Leaderboard

The Stack Snippet at the bottom of this post generates the leaderboard from the answers a) as a list of shortest solution per language and b) as an overall leaderboard.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
## Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
## Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
## Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the snippet:

```
## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```html
<style>body { text-align: left !important} #answer-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } #language-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } table thead { font-weight: bold; } table td { padding: 5px; }</style><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table><script>var QUESTION_ID = 62350; var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe"; var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk"; var OVERRIDE_USER = 45941; var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page; function answersUrl(index) { return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" + QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER; } function commentUrl(index, answers) { return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER; } function getAnswers() { jQuery.ajax({ url: answersUrl(answer_page++), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { answers.push.apply(answers, data.items); answers_hash = []; answer_ids = []; data.items.forEach(function(a) { a.comments = []; var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/); answer_ids.push(id); answers_hash[id] = a; }); if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false; comment_page = 1; getComments(); } }); } function getComments() { jQuery.ajax({ url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { data.items.forEach(function(c) { if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER) answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c); }); if (data.has_more) getComments(); else if (more_answers) getAnswers(); else process(); } }); } getAnswers(); var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/; var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i; function getAuthorName(a) { return a.owner.display_name; } function process() { var valid = []; answers.forEach(function(a) { var body = a.body; a.comments.forEach(function(c) { if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body)) body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>'; }); var match = body.match(SCORE_REG); if (match) valid.push({ user: getAuthorName(a), size: +match[2], language: match[1], link: a.share_link, }); else console.log(body); }); valid.sort(function (a, b) { var aB = a.size, bB = b.size; return aB - bB }); var languages = {}; var place = 1; var lastSize = null; var lastPlace = 1; valid.forEach(function (a) { if (a.size != lastSize) lastPlace = place; lastSize = a.size; ++place; var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html(); answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".") .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user) .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language) .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link); answer = jQuery(answer); jQuery("#answers").append(answer); var lang = a.language; lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text(); languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang.toLowerCase(), user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link}; }); var langs = []; for (var lang in languages) if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang)) langs.push(languages[lang]); langs.sort(function (a, b) { if (a.lang_raw > b.lang_raw) return 1; if (a.lang_raw < b.lang_raw) return -1; return 0; }); for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i) { var language = jQuery("#language-template").html(); var lang = langs[i]; language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang) .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user) .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link); language = jQuery(language); jQuery("#languages").append(language); } }</script>
```

Comment: For bonus points: Input `%dspooky%dme`, validate and return next in series.

Comment: True, but [Dennis would still win](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ftMZn.jpg)

Comment: Will N always be at least 1?

Comment: Who is Dennis? :O

Comment: @NuWin [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) is the way. Dennis is the light.

Comment: @NuWin Dennis is love, Dennis is life

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## gs2, 15 bytes

I outgolfed Dennis!

CP437:

```
spooky•me♣╨V↕0B
```

Hex dump:

```
73 70 6f 6f 6b 79 07 6d 65 05 d0 56 12 30 42
```

At the start of the program, STDIN is pushed (e.g. the string `"3"`) and stored in variable `A`. The first ten bytes of the program push two strings, `"spooky"` and `"me"`, to the stack. Then:

- `d0` pushes variable `A`.
- `56` parses it as a number.
- `12` `30` increments it by two.
- `42` swaps the top two elements on the stack, leaving `"3" "spooky" 5 "me"`.

The final stack is printed as `3spooky5me`.

Comment: Holy hell, that's short. +1

Comment: GJ, but Dennis might come over here and outmod you to preserve his reputation.

Comment: What no how how did you do that

Comment: I just realized... does gs2 stand for "golf script 2"?

Comment: By the way, I've added GS2 to my family of online interpreters, [Try it online!](http://gs2.tryitonline.net/#code=c3Bvb2t54oCibWXimaPilahW4oaVMEI&input=Mg)

Answer (score 29):

## GS2, 17 bytes

```
56 40 27 27 04 73 70 6F 6F 6B 79 05 42 04 6D 65 05
```

I CAN'T OUTGOLF DENNIS HELP

Comment: [relevant](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ftMZn.jpg)

Comment: Man, it's so weird that we currently have 4 languages tied for first and 3 languages tied for second :P

Answer (score 25):

## Stuck, 17 bytes

```
i_2+"spooky";"me"
```

EDIT: GUESS YOU COULD SAY I'M STUCK AT 17 BYTES

Comment: Hey cool, someone actually using Stuck :D

Comment: @Shebang I actually really like Stuck. Although it would be nice if it had some better methods for manipulating arrays.

Answer (score 21):

## GolfScript, 17 bytes

```
~.2+"spooky"\"me"
```

Try it online on [Web GolfScript](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyIyIiAjIFNpbXVsYXRlIGlucHV0IGZyb20gU1RESU4uCgp%2BLjIrInNwb29reSJcIm1lIg%3D%3D).

#### How it works

```
~.2+"spooky"\"me"
~                 # Evaluate the input.
 .2+              # Push a copy and add 2.
    "spooky"      # Push that string.
            \     # Swap it with the computed sum.
             "me" # Push that string.
```

Answer (score 16):

## Chef, 414 bytes

```
S.

Ingredients.
g i
2 g t
115 l s
112 l p
111 l o
107 l k
121 l y
109 l m
101 l e

Method.
Take i from refrigerator.Put e into mixing bowl.Put m into mixing bowl.Put i into mixing bowl.Add t.Put y into mixing bowl.Put k into mixing bowl.Put o into mixing bowl.Put o into mixing bowl.Put p into mixing bowl.Put s into mixing bowl.Put i into mixing bowl.Pour contents of mixing bowl into the baking dish.

Serves 1.
```

A recipe for disaster. Do not try this at home.

Comment: Mm. That's some spooky tastes you got there.

Answer (score 11):

## Pyth - 17 bytes

```
s[Q"spooky"hhQ"me
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%5BQ%22spooky%22hhQ%22me&input=2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4&debug=0).

Answer (score 11):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 18 bytes

Looks like I'm in the second tier of golfing languages here. :^P

```
[a"spooky"a+2"me"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/OlGpuCA/P7tSKVHbSCk3VSn2////xgA)

Takes the number as a command-line argument and puts the appropriate elements in an array, which is joined together and autoprinted at the end of the program.

---

Five and a half years later, here's a much more interesting 18-byte solution:

```
"0spooky2me"RXD_+a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fyaC4ID8/u9IoN1UpKMIlXjvx////xgA)

In the string `0spooky2me`, `R`eplace each digit (built-in regex variable `XD`) with itself plus the command-line argument (`_+a`).

Comment: The built-in regex variable is `XD` lol XD

Answer (score 10):

## CJam, 18 bytes

```
ri_2+"spooky"\"me"
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri_2%2B%22spooky%22%5C%22me%22)

Answer (score 9):

## TeaScript, 18 bytes

```
x+`spooky${x+2}me`
```

Unfortunately this string can't be compressed so this is basically as short as it will get

Comment: Welcome to the 18th byte! :P

Answer (score 8):

## dc, 20 bytes

```
?dn[spooky]P2+n[me]P
```

Answer (score 8):

## Japt, <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
U+"spooky{U+2}me
```

**Japt** (**Ja**vascri**pt** shortened) is a language of my invention. **It is newer than this challenge; thus, this answer is non-competing.** Unlike my other seven unpublished languages, this one has an [actual interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62685/42545) that is currently being developed and is already partially working.

I wanted to post this because I like how it's the same length as all the existing <s>first-place</s> second-place answers. Here's how it works:

```
U+"spooky{U+2}me"    implicit: [U,V,W,X,Y,Z] = eval(input)
U+                   input +
  "spooky     me"     this string
         {U+2}         with input+2 inserted here
                     implicit: output last expression
```

And there you have it. The spec for all functionality used here was finalized on Oct 29th; nothing was changed to make this answer any shorter. Here's the [interpreter](//ethproductions.github.io/japt), as promised.

Comment: I'm sure this was pre-shoco, but I think you could've done `{U}2me` instead of `{U+2}me` :P

Answer (score 7):

## 05AB1E, <s>14</s> 10 bytes

```
DÌs’ÿæªÿme
```

[Try it online.](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RMOMc-KAmcO_w6bCqsO_bWU&input=OQ)

### Explanation

```
DÌs’ÿæªÿme

D                get input n and duplicate it
 Ì               increment by 2
  s              Swap. Stack is now [n+2, n].
   ’ÿæªÿme       Compressed string that expands to "ÿspookyÿme". The first ÿ is then replaced by n and the second by n+2.
```

Comment: This seems to work with `D` removed for 9 bytes

Answer (score 6):

## Julia, 23 bytes

```julia
n->"$(n)spooky$(n+2)me"
```

This creates an unnamed lambda function that accepts an integer and returns a string. The output is constructed using Julia's string interpolation.

Answer (score 6):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish/wiki), 21 bytes

```
I:n"emykoops"6Ro{2+nH
```

I guess I'm... tied with Perl? [Try it online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/?code=I%3An%22emykoops%226Ro%7B2%2BnH&input=3&debug=false).

```
I:n            Input n, output n
"emykoops"     Push chars
6Ro            Output top 6 chars (spooky)
{2+n           Output n+2
H              Output stack and halt (me)
```

Answer (score 6):

## Vitsy, 21 Bytes

Note: the `Z` command was made after this challenge began, but was not made for this challenge.

```
VVN"ykoops"ZV2+N"em"Z
V                      Grab the top item of the stack (the input) and make it a
                       global variable.
 V                     Call it up - push the global variable to the top of the stack.
  N                    Output it as a number.
   "ykoops"            Push 'spooky' to the stack.
           Z           Output it all.
            V2+N       Call the global variable again, add two, then output as num.
                "em"Z  Push 'me' to the stack and output it all.
```

More spoopy variation using multiple stacks (27 Bytes):

```
&"ykoops"&"em"?DN?Z??2+N??Z

&                           Make a new stack and move to it.
 "ykoops"                   Push 'spooky' to the current stack.
         &"em"              Do the last to things with 'me'.
              ?             Move over a stack.
               DN           Output the input.
                 ?Z         Move over a stack (the one with 'spooky') and print it.
                   ??       Move back to the original stack.
                     2+N    Add 2 to the input and output it as a number.
                        ??Z Move to the stack with 'me' in it and print it.
```

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=VlZOInlrb29wcyJaVjIrTiJlbSJa&input=&args=Mw)

Comment: Just wondering, why are strings inverted?

Comment: It's pushing chars to the stack one by one.

Answer (score 6):

## Jelly

**13 bytes**

```
+0,2ż“×¥X“ŀ`»
```

<sup>I CAN'T OUTGOLF QUARTATA HELP</sup>

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=KzAsMsW84oCcw5fCpVjigJzFgGDCuw&input=&args=Mg)

#### How it works

```
+0,2ż“×¥X“ŀ`»  Main link. Input: n

+0,2           Add [0, 2] to n, resulting in [n, n + 2].
     “×¥X“ŀ`»  Yield ['spooky, 'me'] by indexing into a dictionary.
    ż          Zip the results to left and right with each other.
               This yields [[n, 'spooky'], [n + 2, 'me']], which is flattened
               before printing.
```

Comment: One does not simply outgolf... quartata?

Comment: I can't seem to outgolf quartata, but, since the answer is non-competing, I can give some help. [`+2ṭż“×¥X“ŀ\`»`](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@69t9HDn2qN7HjXMOTz90NIIIH20IeHQ7v///xsBAA)

Answer (score 5):

### Javascript(ES6) <s>23</s> 21 Bytes

A simple function that will be crushed by golfing lanqs:

```
_=>_+`spooky${_+2}me`
```

```
_=>`${_}spooky${_+2}me`
```

Special thanks to ETHproductions for saving 2 bytes

Comment: NOICE! You might be able to shorten the template strings, but I can't think of any way to do so

Comment: Two bytes saved: ```_=>_+`spooky${_+2}me` ```

Comment: Thank you, but now the fix seems so obvious I feel stupid. I think this is the shortest possible way to do this in Javascript, I could be wrong( I hope I'm wrong)

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 25 bytes

```rb
->n{"#{n}spooky#{n+2}me"}
```

This creates an unnamed lambda that accepts an integer and returns a string. The string is constructed using Ruby's string interpolation.

Answer (score 5):

## APL, <s>25</s> 22 bytes

```
⍕,'spooky','me',⍨∘⍕2+⊢
```

This creates an unnamed monadic function train that accepts an integer on the left and returns a string.

Numeric values are converted to strings using `⍕`. The array of strings is joined into a single string using `∊`.

[Try it online](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%u2355%2C%27spooky%27%2C%27me%27%2C%u2368%u2218%u23552+%u22A2%u22C4f%202&run)

Saved 3 bytes thanks to Thomas Kwa!

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>55</s> <s>47</s> <s>46</s> <s>42</s> 34 bytes

```php
<?=($a=$argv[1]).spooky.($a+2).me;
```

Accepts the number as command line input.

#### Credits :)

Thanks to manatwork for saving 4 bytes!

Thanks to insertusernamehere for saving 8 bytes!

Comment: `function a($a){echo$a,"spooky",$a+2,"me";}`

Comment: You could *save* **4 bytes** by removing the `"`s.  You could even *save* **4 more bytes** by taking a command line argument and discard the function, like this: `<?=($a=$argv[1]).spooky.($a+2).me;`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Chaîne](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Cha-ne/?code%3D%7Bi~%7D%3A-%2C%7D%3A%7B2%2B%7Dme||input%3D2), 15 bytes

*noncompeting, language postdates question*

```
{i~}:-,}:{2+}me
{i~}            | input duplicate write
    :   :       | access dictionary with inner base-93 key
     -,}        | entry for "spooky"
         {2+}   | push 2, add previous two, write
             me | write me
```

Implicit output.

Comment: The output is `spookyme 4 2" (newline separated)

Comment: @fschmengler I must have messed something up whilst updating the interpreter. Please stand by.

Comment: @fschmengler Alright, bugs have been fixed. It should work now.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```perl
$\=spooky.($_+2).me
```

The code requires the `-p` switch. *Thanks to @Xcali for golfing off 1 byte!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxra4ID8/u1JPQyVe20hTLzf1/3@jf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)

Answer (score 3):

## Lua for windows, 41 bytes

```
n=io.read()print(n.."spooky"..n+2 .."me")
```

test with lua for windows

it takes the input through io.read then stored in variable n then on the same line prints the variable n then "spooky" then n+2 finally it prints "me"

Comment: Remove whitespace and save bytes
`n=io.read()print(n.."spooky"..n+2.."me")`

Comment: @DigitalVeer - Without the whitespace `2.` will be treated as a number.

Comment: p.lua: `print(.....'spooky'.. ...+2 ..'me')`  How to run: `lua51.exe p.lua 2` Size = 35 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <strike>45</strike> 27 bytes

```
Print[#,"spooky",#+2,"me"]&
```

<strike>`g=ToString[#]<>"spooky"<>ToString[#+2]<>"me"&`</strike>

Thanks to Martin Büttner for the significant improvement (and the warm welcome).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Unnamed functions are fine, so you don't need the `g=` and I think `Print[#,"spooky",#+2,"me"]&` should work as well. :)

Comment: What about `Row@{#,spooky,#+2,me}&`?  The output is visually similar if the variables are not defined.

Answer (score 3):

## [Simplex v.0.7](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Simplex/), 20 bytes

Simplex simply isn't feeling golfy today. >_<

```
i@R"spooky"&IIR"me"g
i@                   ~~ take input and copy to register
  R"spooky"          ~~ write that string to the strip (increment byte after every character)
           &II       ~~ write the register (incremented twice) to the strip
              R"me"  ~~ write that string to the strip
                   g ~~ output the strip
```

Comment: You still beat Vitsy. o-o

Comment: @VoteToClose Don't feel too bad. Last Simplex version would've been ~25+ characters. Either way, 20 or 21 bytes doesn't come close to 17 ;-;

Comment: [Dennis wins _again_.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ftMZn.jpg)

Comment: @VoteToClose What did you expect? He's a mod XD

Comment: We need to add [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ftMZn.jpg) to the meme list.

Comment: @VoteToClose You need to do it. For the meme-ness

Answer (score 3):

### C, 58 bytes

```
main(a,b)char**b;{printf("%sspooky%dme",*++b,atoi(*b)+2);}
```

`atoi()` may be unnecessary.

Comment: 1. Fails on my `gcc`, because it depends on evaluation order. 2. Save a byte with `int**b`.

Answer (score 3):

### [Minkolang 0.10](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 49 bytes

I have no way to convert integers to strings (yet!), so this is much longer.

```
"me"nd2+(dl%"0"+$rl:d)"spooky"2g(dl%"0"+$rl:d)$O.
```

[Try it here.](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%22me%22nd2%2B%28dl%25%220%22%2B%24rl%3Ad%29%22spooky%222g(dl%25%220%22%2B%24rl%3Ad)%24O%2E&input=200)

#### Explanation

`(dl%"0"+$rl:d)` does the job of converting an int to a string. If this were replaced by a single character (like `Z`), then my solution would be just **23 bytes**.

```
"me"nd2+Z"spooky"2gZ$O.
```

`nd` takes an integer from input and duplicates it. `2+` adds 2 and `2g` later gets the initial input and puts it on top of stack. `$O.` outputs the whole stack as integers and stops.

Comment: Surely it's shorter to just output the numbers as numbers?

Comment: Outputting as number automatically adds a space to the output. So it'd be "2 spooky4 me".

Answer (score 3):

## Rotor, 15 bytes

```
&"spooky"~2+"me
```

Language was created after the challenge. Does not work in the online interpreter (uses input eval.)

Comment: Dam son. You outgolfed Dennis. Finally. Hooray!

Comment: Rotor is dead to me don't try to resurrect it please.

Comment: Nice job, even in Rotor!! You should reward it with life.

Answer (score 3):

### [Cookie](https://github.com/Ojas-Gulati/cookie), 16 bytes

Note that the recent changes to the Github page were **not** made for this challenge, Cookie is still in development.

```
wŕspooky[r+2]me"
```

Explanation:

```
wŕspooky[r+2]me"
w                 start write command
 ŕ                take input
  spooky          write spooky
        [r+2]     compute input + 2
             me   write me
               "  close write command.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 30 bytes

```
[ dup 2 + [I ${}spooky${}meI]]
```

TIO doesn't have the `interpolate` vocab, so have a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
C<C-r>"spooky<C-r>"<esc><C-a><C-a>ame
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/39nGWbfITqm4ID8/uxLCtkktTrYDMhMhRGJu6v//hpb/dcsA)

#### Explanation

```
C
```

Delete the input number (storing it in the register) and enter insert mode.

```
<C-r>"spooky<C-r>"
```

Insert the number from the register, followed by `spooky`, followed by the number from the register again.

```
<esc><C-a><C-a>
```

Leave insert mode and increment the number under the cursor twice.

```
ame
```

Insert `me` after the number.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 31 bytes

```
lambda n:"%dspooky%dme"%(n,n+2)
```

[Ask and you shall receive.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25070299#25070299)

Comment: Python 3.6+ `lambda n:f'{n}spooky{n+2}me'` for 28 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>39</s> 35 bytes

```
n->"".format("%dspooky%dme",n,n+2);
```

A lambda expression that takes an `int` and returns a string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_(programming_language)), 25 bytes

```
?N:N.!"spooky"2N.+!"me"$
```

Ungolfed:

```
? N:         ~ Read an integer N from STDIN
N. !         ~ Write N to STDOUT
"spooky"     ~ String literals go straight to STDOUT
2 N. + !     ~ Print N+2
"me"
$            ~ End of program
```

Answer (score 2):

## Gema, 21 characters

```
*=*spooky@add{$0;2}me
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ echo -n 42 | gema '*=*spooky@add{$0;2}me'
42spooky44me
```

Answer (score 2):

## jq, 21 characters

(20 characters code + 1 character command line option.)

```
"\(.)spooky\(.+2)me"
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq -r '"\(.)spooky\(.+2)me"' <<< 42
42spooky44me
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=%22%5C%28.%29spooky%5C%28.%2B2%29me%22&j=42) (Passing `-r` through URL is not supported – check Raw Output yourself.)

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 24 bytes

```
echo $1spooky$(($1+2))me
```

Takes input as command line argument

Comment: There is also an old syntax for arithmetic evaluation: `$[`…`]`. It is deprecated, but that usually not holds us back from using it.

Answer (score 2):

### [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```powershell
param($x)"$x`spooky$($x+2)me"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQ6VCU0mlIqG4ID8/u1IFyNU20sxNVfr//78RAA)

Takes input `$x`, constructs and leaves a string on the pipeline with implicit output. The string is formed from `$x` `spooky` `$x+2` `me`, with the trick being the `` ` `` that allows the variable name to be escaped to be just `$x` instead of `$xspooky`.

*-1 byte thanks to Veskah.*

Comment: `param($x)"$x\`spooky$($x+2)me"` is one shorter

Answer (score 2):

## pl, 12 bytes

```
_spooky_2┼me
```

[Try it online.](http://pl.tryitonline.net/#code=X3Nwb29reV8y4pS8bWU&input=NA)

Non-competing since pl was invented after this challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 30 bytes

```
(n:Int)=>s"${n}spooky${n+2}me"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Jolf, 15 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=IsKmanNwb29recKmKzJqbWU&input=MgoKMwoKNA) I forgot about inline string interpolation until after @quartata posted his solution.

```
"¦jspooky¦+2jme
```

### Explanation

```
"¦jspooky¦+2jme
"               string containing
 ¦j              the input,
   spooky        "spooky"
         ¦+2j    2 + the input,
             me  and "me"
                implicitly printed.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 24 bytes

`n->n+"spooky"+(n+2)+"me"`

That moment when Java is actually competitive... (and by competitive I mean top 40 :P)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY4xD4IwEIV3fsWlUxtiY1wciP4DWRiNQy2VFMq1oYWEGH57LUhcXC65@96991oxiYN1Ctu6i7p3dgjggwhaQpsQNwIbXs0@qJ7bMRSZNMJ7uAmN7wxAY1DDS0gF5boCVGHQ2ICkiQCyIh2XLI3dswSEC0Q8XDEn3lnbzSSnmJ9YTnpFYrFq3fg0Sbu/TFbX0Kc8@vW@P0CwPezXi7uEgkGKXNIj23L/@UbPbG@1xA8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), 624 bytes

```
   ^      ^      ^      ^     ^      ^      ^      ^      ^
  / \    / \    / \    / \   / \    / \    / \    / \    / \
 /set\  /out\  /out\  /out\ /out\  /out\  /out\  /out\  /out\
^-----^^-----^ -----^ -----^----- ^----- ^-----^ -----^ -----^
-    ^--    / \    / \    / \    / \    / \   /+\    / \    / \
    /#\    /chr\  /chr\  /chr\  /chr\  /chr\ ^---^  /chr\  /chr\
   ^---   ^----- ^----- ^----- ^----- ^-----/2\  - ^----- ^-----
  /l\    / \    / \    / \    / \    / \    ---   / \    / \
 /ine\  /115\  /112\  /111\  /107\  /121\        /109\  /101\
 -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----        -----  -----
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDBCsIwDIbvfYofPEqpnYj4LqUgs7CBU9n04NN3TdOD3UpdDvmaPw3529d3vA79TU5t5wbnPQCLGCVUWrACUDB0LKHSIgioyb1DpZ6fFUpaBmElhU1AhpiRYXFDyPgAKfHfKOX9yjxxx2XbjaYKGzdnmuD1MmFpN4dqwthCo7@/m232wYuyv@8fjrxofWI0DB1xOEc02iBF0C7c0mGajWwBx6/m/XEG)

Very straightforward. Gets an integer from input and saves it to the blank variable. Prints it. Prints "spooky". Prints blank+2. Prints "me". Follows the same pattern as [Hello, World](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136229/73884), for the most part.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 31 bytes

Not special, just uses some formatting

```
Fn.new{|n|"%(n)spooky%(n+2)me"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikUFyQn59dqWCr8N8tTy8vtby6Jq9GSVUjTxMiAWRpG2nmpirV/g@uLC5JzdUrL8osSdWAyOolJ@bkaBhpav4HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MarioLANG](https://github.com/tomsmeding/MarioLANG), 221 bytes

```
;>+>+>+>+>.>)
:"+"+"+"+"-"-
)++++++++.-:-
+++++++++--+-"
+++++++++.-+-.
+++++++++-.(--
+++++++++-+.--
+++++++++-++--
+++++++++.++--
++++++++++++--
++++++++++++--
++++++++++++--
++++++++++++--
+!+!+!+!+!+!.!
=#=#=#=#=#=#=#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL///f2k4bCvXsNLmslLShUFdJl0tTGwr0dK10uWAcbV1dbV0lBFcPyNVDktXT0EVWDJRH4Wojc/VQudpkcBURUE@Ry1YZGf7/bwQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
╶spooky╶├me）∑
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyNTc2c3Bvb2t5JXUyNTc2JXUyNTFDbWUldUZGMDkldTIyMTE_,i=Mg__,v=8)

Answer (score 2):

### [Aussie++](https://github.com/zackradisic/aussieplusplus), 60 bytes

```
THE HARD YAKKA FOR f IS(n)<BAIL ""+n +"spooky"+(n +2)+"me";>
```

Tested in commit e0091bc.

For some reason, the space in `n +` is required. The empty string at the beginning seems unnecessary but isn't, see [this issue](https://github.com/zackradisic/aussieplusplus/issues/26).

Answer (score 2):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate), 19 bytes

```
$~1spooky${$~1+2}me
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdcGCpaUlaboWm1XqDIsL8vOzK1WqgUxto9rcVIgMVMHiaItYKBMA)

#### Explanation

```
$~1spooky${$~1+2}me
$~1                  First command-line input
   spooky            spooky
         ${     }    Treat the result of this expression as a string:
           $~1         First command-line input
              +2       Plus 2
                 me  me
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 70 bytes

```go
import."fmt"
func f(n int)string{return Sprintf("%dspooky%dme",n,n+2)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LcwxCoMwFMbx2ZziERAStKU4lapr50JPIOqTYPMSYhyKeJIuUujYA_U2Na3Tn48Pfo9nZ5a3req-6lrQlaL8NXrcHT9npa1xfs9Re85wpBpQECjycvBOUTe51o-O4GrX5VHwuBmsMf09bnTLU0opyeS8aeUPCL6QMLEIjQMFpxIO-doCstAkCVd0Cd6NBAolJYtmtiHL8u8X)

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
{it+"spooky${it+2}me"}
```

Comment: At string's ends is shorter to concatenate: `{it+"spooky${it+2}me"}`.

Answer (score 1):

### Burlesque, 21 bytes

```
J2?+Cl"~spooky~me"jf~
```

Needs fixed stack layout. Not usable except as a stand-alone program. Otherwise use one of the versions below that are more generic.

Alternative versions:

```
"~spooky~me"jbxJ2?+_+f~ [24 bytes]
J"spooky"?+j2?+"me"?+?+ [24 bytes, too]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [O](https://github.com/phase/o), 20 bytes

```
j.o"spooky"o))o"me"o
```

Kinda long [Try it online](http://o-lang.herokuapp.com/link/code=j.o%22spooky%22o))o%22me%22o&input=2)

```
j          Get input as Number
.          Clone the number to add to later
o          Print the number
"spooky"o  Print spooky
))o        Increment the input by two and print
"me"o      Print me
```

Answer (score 1):

## JS (ES5) 41

Oh, ES6...

```
function(a){alert(a+"spooky"+(a+2)+"me")}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Coffeescript, 23 bytes

```
(n)->n+"spooky#{n+2}me"
```

Anonymous function that takes `int` `n` and returns `<n>spooky<n+2>me`.

Comment: Nice! You could save two bytes with `(n)->n+"spooky#{n+2}me"`.

Comment: @ETHproductions Didn't think of that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## C++11, <strike>142</strike> <strike>130</strike> 108 bytes

*Self-imposed challenge: no C headers*

```c++
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
[](int x){std::stringstream q;q<<x<<"spooky"<<x+2<<"me";return q.str();}
```

Thanks to [Mego](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45941/mego) for saving a few bytes with <strike>the return logic</strike> everything.

Comment: Good tip. I'll make the changes accordingly.

Comment: That's terrifying, and also really neat.

Comment: Ooh. That's good.

Answer (score 1):

## C# 33 bytes

```
string s(n)=>$"{n}spooky{n+2}me";
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Carrot (version ^3)](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/), 14 bytes

```
#spooky(#+2)me
```

Explanation:

Carets `^` have now been made optional if you do not want to use commands. The `#` is the variable representing the input. Every instance of `#` is replaced with the value of input. Going to the parentheses, the expression inside the parentheses is evaluated and a number is returned.

Test it online [here](https://www.codecademy.com/betaNinja63326/codebits/RSSGcl). Please note that this is not permalinked.

Comment: Did you write this before the challenge, and do you have proof?

Comment: @ThomasKwa I started writing this on the 1st of November. And proof is in Carrot's website

Comment: I might actually start using Carrot. XD

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, 17 bytes

This assumes that the integer `n` may be expressed in unary in the output. Each line would go in its own file, with one byte added per additional file.

```
1+
$_spooky$_11me
```

If the input is `11`, the output is `11spooky1111me`.

For non-unary output (but still unary input), use this (27 bytes):

```
1+
$_spooky$_11me
(\d)+
$#1
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=MSsKJF9zcG9va3kkXzExbWUKKFxkKSsKJCMx&input=MTE)

Comment: Is unary the standard way of expressing numbers in retina?

Answer (score 1):

## ><>, 25 (+2) = 27 bytes

```
:n'emykoops'oooooo{2+noo;
```

Starting with a value (n) on top of the stack from -v (2 byte penalty). Explanation:

```
:            Duplicates top item on stack
 n           Pops and outputs top value on stack as number -> n
  'emykoops' Pushes each character onto the stack
   o         x5 Pops and outputs top value on stack as character -> "spooky"
    {        Shift stack leftwards making input value top value
     2       Pushes 2 on the stack
      +      Pops top 2 elements, sums them and pushes result
       n     Pops and outputs top value on stack as number -> n+2
        o    x2 Pops and outputs top value on stack as character -> "me"
         ;   Ends execution
```

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 20 bytes

```
"me",;⌐@"spooky"@kεj
```

Since this challenge partially inspired this language, I figured I should go ahead and add a solution. [Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=Im1lIiw74oyQQCJzcG9va3kiQGvOtWo&input=Mg)

Comment: A golfing language partially *based on* this challenge got **20** whole bytes?

Comment: @Cyoce I still haven't implemented the parts of the language that were inspired by this challenge (raw strings mode).

Answer (score 1):

### F#, 33 bytes

```
fun n->printf"%ispooky%ime"n<|n+2
```

Answer (score 1):

## Squirrel, 25 bytes

```
@(n)n+"spooky"+(n+2)+"me"
```

Answer (score 1):

## D, 71 bytes

```
import std.string;string s(int i){return format("%sspooky%sme",i,i+2);}
```

More verbose than Java...

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 16 bytes

```
"%spooky%me"J+2J
```

[Try it online.](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=IiVzcG9va3klbWUiSisySg)

Answer (score 1):

### Applesoft BASIC, 28 bytes

```
0input n:?n;"spooky";n+2;"me
```

The question mark expands to `PRINT` and the missing final double quotation mark is implied.

Tested with [Joshua Bell's online emulator](http://www.calormen.com/jsbasic/).

Answer (score 1):

### R, 38 bytes

```
n=scan();sprintf("%dspooky%dme",n,n+2)
```

or (same length)

```
sprintf("%dspooky%dme",n<<-scan(),n+2)
```

Example:

```
n=scan();sprintf("%dspooky%dme",n,n+2)
1: 999
999spooky1001me
```

Comment: `paste0(n<-scan(),"spooky",n+2,"me")` for 35 :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pylongolf](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/pylongolf), 20 bytes

```
_:AA"spooky"A2+"me"~
```

`_` asks for input and `:A` puts it into the variable A.
`A"spooky"` pushes A, and spooky then `A2+` adds the input + 2.
After that we push "me" into the stack and print it with `~`.

Answer (score 1):

## [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), <s>100</s> 99 bytes

```
HAI 1.3
I HAS A J
GIMMEH J
VISIBLE J!
VISIBLE "spooky"!
VISIBLE SUM OF J AN 2!
VISIBLE "me"
KTHXBYE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8nPSc5PSf3/38PRU8FQz5jLU8HDMVjBUcGLy93T19fVA8gI8wz2dPJxVfBShDOVigvy87MrlRAiwaG@Cv5uCl4Kjn4KRkgKc1OVuLxDPCKcIl3//zcGAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 21 bytes

```
[:2+,'spooky'#`'me'+]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/P9rKSFtHvbggPz@7Ul05QT03VV079r@DVTqXqUK6Qn5pCZcRhP4PAA)

Function returning the string.

### Explanation

```
[:2+,'spooky'#`'me'+]
[                   ]  function                stack: (y)
 :                     duplicate               stack: (y y)
  2+                   add 2                   stack: (y y+2)
    ,                  pair                    stack: ((y y+2))
     'spooky'#`        join by "spooky"        stack: ("{y}spooky{y+2}")
               'me'+   append the string "me"  stack: ("{y}spooky{y+2}me")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 24 bytes

```
{"${it}spooky${it+2}me"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BCsIwFET3PcUQXPwgFemyUF0L7jxBwCih7U9pv0IJOXtMzKyGecPM6GVynL5mwrZ4P@496Mai0V7wkNXxG0MK6hCcxFoo9tjF2aqYXh/GbByTRmiQVXYYA2i15nl3bDO59lBnpf@86CQ@P1ANlnwhVJeJtW5i6n4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 39 bytes

```forth
: f 0 2dup .r ." spooky"2 m+ .r ." me";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKRgoGKWUFijoFSnoKSkUF@TnZ1cqGSnkakNFclOVrIHqChRAioyhggq6dgpKQL3JRQrWXEYKBVzGQGwKxIYGCgX/AQ)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f            \ start a new word definition
  0 2dup       \ add 0 to the top of the stack and duplicate the top two stack values
  .r           \ print the input with no following space
  ." spooky"   \ print "spooky"
  2 m+ .r      \ add 2 to the input and print with no following space
  ." me"       \ print "me"
;              \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ïöeO¬‼3ì╡☻↔G
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8b94654faa13338db5021d47&i=2%0A3%0A99&a=1&m=2)

Uses an unterminated template literal to embed instructions in an output string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Assembly (MIPS, SPIM)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spim), 221 bytes

```
.data
a: .asciiz "spooky"
c: .asciiz "me"
.text
.globl main
main:
li $2 5
syscall
la $9 a
la $10 a
move $8 $2
l:
move $4 $8
li $2 1
syscall
li $2 4
move $4 $9
syscall
bne $10 $9 e
la $9 c
addi $8 2
j l
e:
li $2 10
syscall
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7RCoMwDHzPVwTpc1HnYPo3sZaRLbVCZcz9fFdLnXtJcpe7S8LCLkY90UpAA2oKhvmDVVi8f24VmD/O2Qr0at8r6Lv4UdARz7CXAYRRtXiFsAVDIiCEqkfKvanT4PzLorolFchQUJeI4mxOZ8bdKel/q3G2OS0l23LBAE0T78EtPFDAHq809WGL8fIF)

Couldn't get SPIM and TIO to play nice with argc/argv, so had to take it via input. String formatting in Assembly isn't pleasant.

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-no` 13 bytes

```
:&spooky&2+me
```

This was *way* too spooky. It's not even October!

Pushes the evaluated input and stores it in the register, pushes the sequence `spooky`, adds two to the value in the register and then pushes the sequence `me`.

Uses the latest version of the interpreter which hasn't been updated on TIO thus far.

Answer (score 1):

### [tq](https://github.com/A-ee/tq), 16 bytes

```
?"spooky"?+2"me"
```

### Explanation

````
# Define an array with 4 items
?                # First item: input
 "spooky"        # Second item: "spooky"
         ?+2     # Third item: input + 2
            "me" # Fourth item: "me"

# Print without a separator
```
````

Comment: I may start trying to make it a golfing language as well. I am thinking about adding increment-by-2 and length-2 strings.

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/w-golf/w) `d`, 14 bytes

```
♠╚z[·7♦÷U# 1╘╖
```

### Explanation

Uncompressed:

```
"a"spooky"a2+"me"
```

```
""                 % Push an empty string for the first operand to render
  a                % The 1st operand
   "spooky"        % Push "spooky"
           a2+     % The 1st operand + 2
              "me" % Push me
```

Answer (score 1):

## BRASCA, 27 bytes

```
ig:an`ykoops`[o]A}}n`em`[o]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVvrctu2Ev6vp0Dt01qqJVvOpUl8LLd2krZumzhju3N6xuMykAhJTEiCIcHImjZ99XQXvIggIRGMr55pY5PA7rdXLIBlMBdT7j98GoSfHS/goSDRPOoSj4ppaxxyjwjHYyR75TIWJI9D6tvwT/oC/4L/JqyVPhAhHbEhHb1vtUYujSJyGNJoRJ/j77stAj9ra2unAgZ0ScgmTiRYGBGgQj7S0KFDl0UwQA602ZhYluM7wrLaEXPHnd2WfIE/65KGnJiTyV/i4K1IDhiQ8wv1OYVnffXRUHm04HEQMjJjwIDajj8h7CMLQWv4K43IaEpBVuT7fZlxCEMsj9sM6P5I3YgVcL9xAmb3HJ/YVND8sTMmPpcmgOnAbMuJqBDzdmc3H1KgDwMsnA7kFzMQZbtzvrvb27lQJo15SKwusQgwZX7ssZAK1i6RKjHSMEN7RbErkKn65hxZditPyzhUy2zRIGC@3eah3U4Idzr5cAY6q5McvGSh1Z8pOlFqnCFjPgnACILZZM5EyT7URVXNrWxE1UZnUyciM8d1SSQ4@ACF38SUkSEY/D0TJOCRIxzulzxuNnVcZrmcBxEQ/euTQpGREToEOiySCjgyD1UCOMJK31S9dJQ4VFFu@Rwiz3VGECVg21wY/QjBA1Xc9TdxNCUwcQgcBZfQpHnyCAxggJUMkD7TxdEFb6laFN8XqX@kbswIHy8iBjlpuOD7lAf@upIJuo0c1FkuyJALAakKOK8Uy0rG1Unn@BELRbufDKkX0AgBzlD5L5d8AaAqPNhVZucSCx5kibOcaHKyapiFTMShX/C8aiSmQwrAkE0SuyU0tSrgQVH4W4DZzzR2CmGMgLLFI8cUMWFlD1OTZH@q@LKnZAAxSdc06YpmqXKhoARrefZQN3tYnV3wuSL2jSh1QW0AY7K7LomUEExk7Ojl7jcVt0p62NErpZ@a8ATX44hpRZZvyk5V4JON6OS0pLcgKZf5EzHVO2zyrkw3dTV42V6wKIRm7MKCK6nJFYLgCkFc0Adpl9eNTs5qGDuunTws8xPMC9TCBp9YUHcoNYf6EhZGl32IuWCKdbA4yJYzSD7c83CFqlYKuPiUagQwa4X0PulXC4nKqN6A7CijpI9UcQ6WUyvJWgaWCYLudr6WrLrKvHSinnzmhpliOlWwRQYXjRiAd4RYRElGamZYVk2cyzkXMClDVD8lG4mz5PTVMmys1Wr6LIxZvW0H5MFqTm8bm6M4rALClD5OrCefelML9yCnc8hYHqHhBCLBF7B9CeSeCctA2NJsBXMyJntjULlPPbZffTsiexg2@63WGYd4ws0NhPYwnnRJDHlrbG@PMNSAC7Ux34y3R1s4NHL5jNh85hMeiyAW6fBoexRJYA7ui5CnZUmJLcujUBdbqQkTAGCIwtYrdbIUW15Jrn12JrvUfzt/jz7z9pxfHHz65L9lHv76Od2tJXmMHGJCSjIk5i@PBkWSxXSVpT7yCmDJ0fLvJPkVIOSl7p7MnYU3xWQXzlWz5bYukjrXkL0oJ4V0jLI/W@p4lQfrRC68e5AX99UCdkXu6WvCqqC1YnHdr@aBim/vmJPbMSD3wJzcAwNyD83JPTQg98ic3CMDco/NyT02IPedObnvDMg9MSf3xIDcU3NyTw3IPTMn98yAnNvAjU3C4rcG9Ew8jzWICxPjvmwQGCaBZjeIDBPzvmjgyyaxMW3gLibe/HMTfzFxmF8bETSh@NfaLll/wUYhw1rBlHj2CKvAnknG/oRsjvwrsNk0YRMiG7ncncjDXR0fuliB9VWsBGMyCPcgDu455Elye9glFFDqLbREQqfTqi7YUoBktYfaaUrDWsE33m6sdAz1aFdbEBtV1mUp5MlXTTmzuXPRWUVIqag2cYdV1cgrijvbAPd1vHBevhT7JvrBgW3fsAPoXHaTGvhpD/GdxkO8dRB3ALJnAvJbBPkqdoUTuPM7APmtCcjtJLEINgHvsZ2PTqTbZd482O1tE7RfS5VyO3b5HWD82gTinwjx5WXA/WWJ@oatbmT2SAbQh/AqCKvM8RJxawwbv/TXCBi0aaejS9KHjpg5sL1tkJX@QdCvj8@uFfM/Jur6RubD1y/uwJ7fmOD7G/Edn9wBvL9N4FkI7487wfcn4NN436l2E18BThF4IM/d@eIs@2BlqVC8RwACBuoZarkcmnMZmnA5kFyyKxozYdQ7BDNpDvV8DhvwMZKni3zS8/wlhzIKh@zgv5bwLhK2Y7w6lef3IAofr@DwpZmHXmVkBfV/VdSL6zdT4NmNnCmqbDy9hgkVaTyUxuMfVfVjfCREtCyTy7AvMkaGTZIwwPcqx1dStLyLSw8@6/E11bkxvqBGf8SXfT6R3i88HvvCdAfnL3Zw/W4ydcUezthG12OnNzV2ukd6WO0LV/SH72WyTFq40maJfm/nwRNTv8v7vdqwzyyfK3QMAHyVr3GLe9bapK05y0hvYk1Y/gdZRjMaSEOLGSeOYF5EuH/lZH7jGX9oIN@JtCkX2SIlpiFjtyvj6MYVMbqKyrT3ORU9nqIeR9zHddPPlQnukhCObt9PMMYigSJt4j/UKMImZTGWO0DaSIBsNja23nHHl@z8ziKR5Qdf2NKwPOmNMM1BMimkvsKVXjq7/kSviXIQvIE6nFQdUPYJAkQcB1N@mvvaPd35uCJUN03RSkuEItdysQBKMnl/QB49Tbtc8e@9AXn8ZPk85cQRWJxLJHiTL6cD6Hq5j4pyL/riEg20N29N7r4q9rMvlhogt@rFvpTlrwNEQru@ZF/pdxXafxRpmxTWJot6hUuMXH73e6dakr5pGSKbeJJobnaSDsnANskzv6c4J0txFnPKZZJTLis5pVXnBmqn03WLqTkTONo@NnA0Lo9aZH8GdoMfnD4/Okq7Huu8btGKUGlFXtqOUBKl2sOsvYzAHzmkPZqq10CdLoS1PdjYMLD08VJRTYLg7qXNg6@J0L4qdJpB76@Bi8ZtIObr5WLeV@NqDLsQWBPPz7kvQu6SH10@q1fIHirkNxZFUEfTm74BQfXt0UaJa0dPiZmoumm70T7q4icwj2xpvx117N9fdQzklc6HGNz6FhQxGNxbTWz8fwM0ccjEjDH/PmwtUV9YXY7wf/fXgX5ABzpjoefgxqx1PUkRvwBjl44wqS3XEQDkQ1u2BlOXvIu9oCaxS62jXvu1@qi2INQieoeIfgEUWM3NoLCOmvQ4qP0z9dx@ybnhJ4rN2PVUdpsG7M6R3f@w7bUne2arfdhVdSc171dY9K7cYCk7pd7ORY2FlkmVC1XsHa9tptVKe1GSFpbkm5J1/0ZFNfGk56u7ekrf5Jl1Cp0Z0ky@4pM0W@rOJflmRUoRhEweyET556v4iWTaDlXtoNf3Ruub5tfP8HMXR0BpOCazKfNhi8@BcSijSjhgU2A7ht27XdMf3azfSv2sJUdzjKxlD4E8V3ZEyzyZV5qwUnClToX1V/IKJfuIs/zxplEKZJcjFgjyK5sPOSQe7LUJwzgQpW@hqtk8nfhS/gNpGw1ZEmf9lHss@fh1xnxBZiH3J108CeYzMA4BTlyFm5TSay9PTo5PdolueunuNZmQf969Benao8ICcOVD@IIIyXcAR6njpp8ztJpuHBZjlRAAH9PsMFbe817hqJIOVlYhGowY@nqM1c0qrduzLSGuD9AFbVolqyWX6rNKboXYjUWuF7e5qEvFxJ/Pjx70/wU)

### Explanation

```
<implicit input>             - Push STDIN on the stack
ig                           - Turn the codepoints of 0-9 into 0-9, and concatenate stack
  :a                         - Store a copy into register A
    n                        - Print the original (this disables implicit output)
     `ykoops`[o]             - Push and print "spooky"
                A}}          - Get the copy from register A and increment twice
                   n         - Print the incremented copy.
                    `em`[o]  - Push and print "me"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```bash
<<<$1spooky$[$1+2]me
```

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGxbC4ID8/u1IlWsVQ2yg2N/X/f9P/pgA)

Comment: What's the `\​` for?

Comment: Huh. I thought the shell needed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Swift, 26 bytes

```swift
{n in"\(n)spooky\(n+2)me"}
```

[TIO link](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/J7VEIc1KQcMzr0RTQddOIbikKDMvXcFWoTpPITNPKUYjT7O4ID8/uxLI0jbSzE1VquXS11fADuKK83NKSzLz8xQyUotS65AAF1dafpFCJtBIBUM9PT1zhWoukIYCoGUlGmkamZqaXLX//wMA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 28 bytes

```python
lambda n:f'{n}spooky{n+2}me'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7LDoIwEEX3fsXdkLaxccFDExJWfoa4qEKxEaaE4gIJ315ratzNmcyZe8dlfljKvK5q36vh1ihQqdlKmxutfS4r7dNtaJnXdsJduVbC2f41G0swhLcZ@aSoa3kqj0LiwtLo5cGRYFmkIlIe6RipiHQKdBXlDlDOtdMMzb85AlX1jwrX57BDzZKmZmhMA7IzxmCAd2FKnDgwJOCx4u@F8B8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>37</s> 33 bytes

Thanks @xigoi for tip on removing i32 type signature for n

```rust
|n|{print!("{}spooky{}me",n,n+2)}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsMgFAX3nuKZlVK7UAsNhJ6kdFGKgjT5CcYUivHsNnX15sEwcVtT9YTpGUhIZAaMLsHjxupOe15ioMRFl8u6zPP7m8vkOkWKTkaWOhy6nyMCAuHjXvxuFXRvrrZXOFutYM1Fm//oR4sfvghyaNTaI3HRfmGl/gA)

Comment: You don't need the `:i32`.

Comment: cool i added it

Answer (score 1):

## [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic), 52 bytes

```
INPUT n
?MID$(STR$(n),2)"spooky"MID$(STR$(n+2),2)"me
```

Try it at [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack).

#### Explanation

QBasic's annoying number-to-string formatting is on full display here. Printing a number directly adds a leading and trailing space, so that's out. `PRINT USING` seems tailored for fixed-width columns and doesn't do well with numbers of different lengths. `STR$(n)` is a little better: it only adds a leading space, which we can remove by taking a substring starting at the second character with `MID$`.

```
INPUT n                                       Get a number from the user
?                                             Print
 MID$(STR$(n),2)                              The number w/o leading space
                "spooky"                      That string
                        MID$(STR$(n+2),2)     The number + 2 w/o leading space
                                         "me  That string (close-quote implied)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 142 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][T  N
S T _Print_as_integer][S S S T  T   T   N
_Push_7_y][S S T    T   T   T   N
_Push_-7_k][S S T   T   T   N
_Push_-3_o][S N
S _Duplicate__o][S S T  T   S N
_Push_-2_p][S S S T N
_Push_1_s][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate_top][N
T   S S N
_Jump_to_Label_DONE_if_0][S S S T   T   T   S S T   S N
_Push_constant_114][T   S S S _Add][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_DONE][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][S S S T    S N
_Push_2][T  S S S _Add][T   N
S T _Print_as_integer][S S S T  T   S T T   S T N
_Push_109_m][T  N
S S _Print_as_character][S S S T    T   S S T   S T N
_Push_101_e][T  N
S S _Print_as_character]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##TUxBCoAwDDs3r8g39hyRgd4GCj6/ZqmKbSFJk/ba9rMfY1l7JkmoNYFwiWlpwvjAIZECoM4QfPYiYckob0YIGz@nXnswgyX5ysx2Aw) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Push 0
Integer n = STDIN as number
Print n as integer to STDOUT
Push codepoint-integers c for "ykoops", each lowered by 114
Start LOOP:
  If top == 0: Go to function DONE
  Add 114 to the top c
  Print c as character to STDOUT
  Go to next iteration of LOOP

function DONE:
  Print n as integer to STDOUT
  Print "me" as characters to STDOUT
  (stop the program implicitly with an error: no exit defined)
```

The constant `114` is generated [by this Java program](https://tio.run/##fVLda9swEH/vX3HoSUapyWB7qB1RWujAsHRQp9uglCG7aqJWkTXpHAgjf7sn1x9xttEXSdzd70N39yJ24vzl6bVpSi28h6VQ5vcZgK0LrUrwKDBcu0o9wTakaI5OmfXDI4ioLQPoAuCkrzUCB/Ewf0zfMsog@K3QWvo2kRmUa@ni5dWPn9@uvtzfzCDjF@mUZKi@G8gI6fJf71c3d8lz5WhLqniWqsWHT/NUMdbbOBrhhMxwZvmABWhxxR4lFElnM15LvA4BT6MRHvw@Ay04VxGUlUFlatnppmMF8iC/qr5vVMBaUcprZYTbd8q0OFdROmGjGMtftdCe2qkMBIsudtLqQPBZOY/Uziwj@W1OJvgDSO0lnOKQuUnF@LIch/AQDPIu1tKscUMjWIytnRj5p9sT7sncjjTHdBbi6lSyO/O9R7mNqxpjG5qC2lDSwTlhAykjaZghYRkjkABh7zU1i3rZv5npqf23qsNZOPqV7dfhPe52l0zfkJ1wYbwkzwmjhvP5JSGJWYRrRRIyDmbYwDIZthmrE8o2Gy0FbmJReGqi6H@rhoyXi48Xl4E3CfzppH9OYu1MqCC3pPvRoWkab6vqdf8H), based on [this Whitespace tip of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158232/52210).

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$17\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 13.993 bytes

```
%"%spooky%me"$w}}
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyIlXCIlc3Bvb2t5JW1lXCIkd319IiwiMiJd)

Sadly, "%spooky%me" is incompressible in Fig.

```
%"%spooky%me"$w}}
               }} # Increment twice
              w   # Wrap it in a list with the original number
             $    # Reverse the list
%"%spooky%me"     # Replace all '%' in "%spooky%me" with the elements in ^
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 23 bytes

```
\&spooky&me|Ig0bb1+2bb2
```

[Try it Online!](http://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%5C%26spooky%26me%7CIg0bb1%2B2bb2&inputs=2)

## Explanation

```
           |                 everything before this is input
\                            as input, take an input string
 &spooky                     ...and "spooky" (hard-coded)
        &me                  ...and "me" (hard-coded)
            I                split input list and store in consecutive memory slots
             g0              get the first element
               b             add this to the print buffer
                b1           add the element in memory slot 1 ("spooky")     
                  +2         add 2 to the top of the stack
                    b        add the top of the stack to the print buffer
                     b2      add "me" to the print buffer (buffer output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 25 bytes

```
$[n]->~"|n|spooky|n+2|me"
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?8jkcND)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `J`, \$ 19 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 16 bytes

(actually 15.64 bytes but the leaderboard doesn't take floats)

```
D2+"spooky"s"me"ZMr
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhabXYy0lYoL8vOzK5WKlXJTlaJ8iyAyUAVLo5W8lGIXGkF4AA)

**Explanation:**

```python
D2+"spooky"s"me"ZMr   # Implicit input
D2+                   # Duplicate and add 2
   "spooky"s          # Push "spooky" and swap
            "me"      # Push "me"
                ZMr   # Push the stack, reversed
                      # J flag joins by ""
                      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `j`, 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ƙ`me+‘ọṣ‘$
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UpZS7IKlpSVpuhabj81MyE3VftQw4-Hu3oc7FwMZKkuKk5KLofILFppCGAA)

##### Explanation

```python
ƙ`me+‘ọṣ‘$  # Implicit input
ƙ           # Increment the input twice
 `me+       # Append the string "me"
     ‘ọṣ‘   # Push compressed string "spooky"
         $  # Push the input again
            # Implicit output of joined stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 17 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
$"_spooky_me"∶+2.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=U3Bvb2t5IOKGkCAkIl9zcG9va3lfbWUi4oi2KzIuCgpTcG9va3kgMgpTcG9va3kgMw==)

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, 33 bytes

```
@(x)fprintf('%dspooky%dme',x,x+2)
```

Pretty self explanatory. Tried a few ways and this was the shortest I could find.

You should be able to run this with the **Octave** [online interpreter](http://www.octave-online.com).

Answer (score 0):

## O, 20 characters

```
Q"spooky"Q2+"me"+++p
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ o.sh 'Q"spooky"Q2+"me"+++p' <<< 42
42spooky44me
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Fourier](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fourier), 32 bytes

```
I~zo115a-3avaa-4a121az+2o109a-8a
```

Still using @isaacg's golfing algorithm ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 38 bytes

```
a n=show(n)++"spooky"++show(n+2)++"me"
```

Defines a function named `a` that takes a `Num` `n`. Returns `<n>spooky<n+2>me`.

Comment: You can save a byte by writing `show n` instead of `show(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 26 bytes

```
#(str %"spooky"(+ 2%)"me")
```

First post. It's a function, as required. I *think* I took as many liberties with the tokenizer as possible, but I don't know. Here it is in action in the REPL:

```
user=> #(str %"spooky"(+ 2%)"me")
#<user$eval1176$fn__1177 user$eval1176$fn__1177@2d2d2f69>
user=> (*1 55)
"55spooky57me"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Dart, 27 Bytes

```
t(n)=>'${n}spooky${n+2}me';
```

Unremarkable but competitive.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf!

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, 79 bytes

```
: f ( x -- ) dup 2 + [ number>string ] bi@ "spooky" swap "me" 4array concat . ;
```

First stab at it, just did it the obvious way.

Answer (score 0):

### Lua, 41 Bytes

There's [this other lua answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62410/41019), but it doesn't work anymore since lua 5.3. It will now print `2spooky4.0me` Here comes a code working under all versions of lua, and who's still in 41 Bytes:

```lua
print(("%dspooky%dme"):format(...,...+2))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [,,,](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata/wiki/Code-page)

```
:↓2+"spooky"↓↓"me"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Acc!!](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 99 bytes

```
N
Write _
Write 115
Write 112
Write 111
Write 111
Write 107
Write 121
Write _+2
Write 109
Write 101
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@PK7wosyRVIR5KGxqawllGcJYhJsvAHMYygonFa8N1GFjCWYb//xsDAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), <s>20</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
ì¯spooky]ì..ìme"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@///wmkPriwvy87MrYw@v0dM7vCY3Ven/f0MjAA)

```
ì¯spooky]ì..ìme"
ì                 « implicit integer input, convert to string     »;
 ¯                « copy input to memory                          »;
  spooky          « push the ASCII character codes for each letter in `spooky` individually »;
        ]         « copy memory to stack                          »;
         ì        « convert string to integer                     »;
          ..      « increment twice                               »;
            ì     « and back to string                            »;
             me   « push character codes for `me`                 »;
               "  « stringify the entire stack                    »;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python ≥ 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/), 28 bytes

```python
lambda x:f'{x}spooky{x+2}me'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKk29uqK2uCA/P7uyukLbqDY3Vf1/QVFmXolGmoaRpuZ/AA)

Makes use of [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498), a feature that was introduced in Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 26 bytes

```
INPUT N?N;"spooky";N+2;"me
```

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 40 bytes

```
SELECT CONCAT(n,'spooky',n+2,'me')FROM t
```

Input taken via a pre-existing table **t** with integer column **n**, [per our input standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

`CONCAT` does an implicit type conversion, otherwise I'd have to do something like `CONVERT(n,varchar(9))`.

Answer (score 0):

## MATL, 18 bytes

```
'spooky'yUQQV'me'v
```

[Try it on MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=%27spooky%27yUQQV%27me%27v&inputs=%272%27&version=20.9.1)

Answer (score 0):

### [OCL](http://ostracodfiles.com/pumpkin/ocl2.html), <s>52</s> 46 bytes

```
Function a b Print b+"spooky"+(b + 2)+"me" End
```

This one is pretty straight forward, I just wanted to show off an obscure language.

Edit: I found out you can omit the spaces between the pluses when doing concatenation, but not addition. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 23 bytes

```
(a:q)."spooky".a+2."me"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fI9GqUFNPqbggPz@7UkkvUdtITyk3Ven/f2MA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü╫2┐╚╘Wö»§W╟╛╨
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81d732bfc8d45794af1557c7bed0&i=3)

#### Unpacked (16 bytes)

```
.me;2+`tNCrf`,Wp
.me                 Literal "me"
   ;2+              Peek from input stack, push to stack, and add 2
      `tNCrf`       Literal "spooky"
             ,      Pop from input stack; push to stack
              Wp    Pop and print everything from the stack with no additional newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 22 bytes

```
=A1&"spooky"&A1+2&"me"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 18 bytes

```
i:2+"me"S9´334E{@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/TykhbKTdVKdjy0BZjYxPXaof//40A)

Saves 1 byte by using `9´334E` to pull "spooky" out of the word dictionary. `8b*E` for "me" is the same length.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
`èï`ri@°+T°
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YInoG%2b%2bMYHJpQLArVLA&input=Mg)

### [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
+`spooky{+2}´
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=K2BzcG9va3l7KzJ9tA&input=Mg)

Answer (score 0):

## AWK, 21 bytes

```
$0=$0"spooky"$0+2"me"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxcBWxUCpuCA/P7tSScVA20gpN1Xp/39DLiMuYy4TLlMA)

Substitutes the input for `(input)spooky(input+2)me`. As the new value of `$0` is not zero nor null, prints `$0`.

Answer (score 0):

### [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 39 bytes

```
w=io.write w(...)w'spooky'w(...+2)w'me'
```

Test

```
> lua -v & echo -------- & lua ./spooky.lua 2
Lua 5.4.0  Copyright (C) 1994-2020 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
--------
2spooky4me
```

Answer (score 0):

### JAVA, 60 bytes

```
class p {String main(int n) {return n+"spooky"+(n+2)+"me";}}
```

Works fine on blueJ but not on TIO idk why?

Comment: It might be because your main function does not seem standard, it should be `public static void main(String[] args) { ... }` and parse args[] accordingly before calculating : `int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);`. You could lose the spaces before the opening braces and save some bytes

Comment: ARE JVM for blueJ and TIO different?

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Ṫ`, 12 bytes

```
:⇧‛me«½↵*←«∇
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuaoiLCIiLCI64oen4oCbbWXCq8K94oa1KuKGkMKr4oiHIiwiIiwiMiJd)

2spooky4joe

### Explained

```
:⇧‛me«½↵*←«∇
:⇧             # Without popping, push input + 2 - this leaves the stack as [input, input + 2]
  ‛me          # push the string "me"
     «½↵*←«    # and the string "spooky"
           ∇   # rotate the top three items and output the sum of the stack
```

Comment: I don't think this code works anymore (maybe it worked on previous versions?), but replacing the `~` with a `:` fixes it: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuaoiLCIiLCI64oen4oCbbWXCq8K94oa1KuKGkMKr4oiHIiwiIiwiMiJd "Vyxal - Try it Online!")

Answer (score 0):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 72 bytes

```lisp
(load library
(q((N)(strcat(string N)(join2(q spooky)(q me)(string(a N 2
```

Anonymous function that takes a number and returns a name (tinylisp's equivalent of a string). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYkxDoMwEAT7vGLLvS7wEBpecAlRdGB8xnbj1xuQqGY0Uy22YCX1zuC6INgna24vLph5kJOw1PzVesPiH1dY3eLIAyW5b00u23/yfComjJ27JszgUB3DW6Sf)

#### Ungolfed/explanation

```lisp
(load library)         ; Needed for strcat, join2, and ungolfed aliases

(lambda (N)            ; Anonymous function with one argument
  (strcat              ; Concatenate these two names as a single string:
    (string N)         ; Convert the input number to a string, and
    (join2             ; Join these strings together:
      (q spooky)       ;   "spooky" and
      (q me)           ;   "me", with the following separator:
      (string          ;   Convert to a string
        (add2 N 2))))) ;   the input number plus 2
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 39 bytes

```
x=int(input());print(f"{x}spooky{x+2}me)
```

*Don't remove the `int()`. That will cause an error.
Tested on `Python 3.10.1 (v3.10.1:2cd268a3a9, Dec  6 2021, 14:28:59) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin`*

Comment: You are missing a quote mark before the last closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>30</s> 28 bytes

```
•Fmt∾"spooky"∾"me"∾˜·•Fmt+⟜2
```

Anonymous tacit function. [Try it at BQN online](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oCiRm104oi+InNwb29reSLiiL4ibWUi4oi+y5zCt+KAokZtdCvin5wyCgpGwqgg4p+oMiwgNCwgOCwgOTnin6kK)

#### Explanation

Reading right-to-left:

- `+⟜2` adds 2 to the argument
- `•Fmt` converts that number to a string
- `·` helps with parsing
- `"me"∾˜` concatenates `me` to the end of the string
- `"spooky"∾` concatenates `spooky` to the beginning of the string
- `•Fmt∾` concatenates the argument, stringified, to the beginning of the string

Answer (score 0):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 24 bytes

```
'me',~":,'spooky',":@+&2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8GCpaUlaboWN_XSFGytFNRzU9V16pSsdNSLC_LzsyvVdZSsHLTVjLhSkzPyFdLU7BTsrBQy9QwNILqgmmGGAAA)

If you've seen the BQN or APL golfs then you've seen this one.

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
k╕o3╣Rk⌠ûme
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/70dSp@caPpi4Oyn7Us@Dw7tzU//8NuYy4LLkMDQwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
k           # Push the input-integer
 ╕o3        # Push compressed string "spoo"
    ╣R      # Push compressed string "ky"
      k     # Push the input-integer again
       ⌠    # Increase it by 2
        ûme # Push string "me"
            # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

`k...k⌠` could alternatively have been `└)...@` for the same byte-count: [try it online](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9tYXRoZ29sZv//4pSUKeKVlW8z4pWjUkDDu21l//8xCjIKOQoxMDA).

```python
└           # Increase the (implicit) input-integer by 1 without popping
 )          # Pop and increase it by 1 again
       @    # Reverse triple-swap the top three values on the stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 26 bytes

```
:n'ykoops'oooooo2+n'em'oo;
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiOm4neWtvb3BzJ29vb29vbzIrbidlbSdvbzsiLCJpbnB1dCI6IiIsInN0YWNrIjoiMyIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyJ9)