# Make every consonant after a vowel uppercase

Tags: code-golf, string

I have a string like this:

```
s = "helloworldandhellocodegolf"
```

I want to make every [consonant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonant) after a [vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel) uppercase.

Desired output:

```
heLloWoRldaNdheLloCoDeGoLf
```

As you can see, `l` gets uppercased because it's right after the vowel `e` etc..

If there are repeated vowels, like:

```
s = "aabeekad"
```

Desired output:

```
s = "aaBeeKaD"
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

<sub>The consonants are all alphabet characters except for `aeiou`.</sub>

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the input consists only of letters?

Comment: @dingledooper Yes.

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to only be lowercase? The question doesn't specify, and almost all current answers fail with uppercase vowels

Comment: @jezza_99 Yes, lowercase.

Comment: Do you consider `Y` to be a vowel of consonant?

Comment: @mousetail There's already a footnote about that. (But it should probably be stated at the beginning.)

Comment: Is trailing space allowed? Please incorporate the answer to this and other comments into the challenge text

Comment: the `s =` and quotations around the string arent necessary in the challenge body

Comment: Can we input/output via a list of characters (using default I/O rules)? Or list of codepoints?

Comment: More test cases would improve this challenge—for example, one that ends with a vowel; one that has two vowels in a row that aren't the same; one that has two consonants in a row after two vowels in a row....

Answer (score 10):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 47 bytes

Expects and returns a string.

```javascript
s=>Buffer(s).map(c=>c^s&~(s=68174912>>c)&32)+''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYy7DsIwDAB3PqNDmwhRqQXxGJKBD0EyjlOgJq5iHhu/HipGxtOd7gYvUMzX6bFKEqhEV9T54zNGykZte4fJoPN40vpj1G333W5z6Hrv0dbr3i6bpqAkFaaWZTDRVBdilrdkDpDCD3AeD8KxsnbxFwOciUYIsypf)

#### How?

The constant \$68174912\$ (which I've already used [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201521/58563)) is a bitmask describing the positions of the vowels:

```
00000100000100000100010001000000
     v     v     v   v   v
zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[
```

#### Commented

```javascript
s =>           // s = input string
Buffer(s)      // turn it into a buffer
.map(c =>      // for each ASCII code c:
  c ^          //   toggle the case if
  s &          //   the previous letter was a vowel
  ~(           //   and the current letter is a consonant
    s =        //   save in s the new state obtained by
      68174912 //   right-shifting the bit-mask
      >> c     //   by c positions (mod 32)
  ) & 32       //   isolate the case bit
) + ''         // end of map(), coerce back to a string
```

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

Expects and returns an array of ASCII codes.

```javascript
a=>a.map(p=c=>c^p&~(p=68174912>>c)&32)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY07DsIwEAV7jpEi8haslID4FHbBFSgRSIs/IeB4LcdAx9VNRIVERfdminlXetCoUx/zPLCxxclCUhEOFEWUWip9ivVrmqtNs15um1YpDfWihaI5jOwteu7E7u6cTegSD8KJAyJ@m@pivecnJ28omA/o6atj7yo4AmDmfU596ATA7I8s0dnaG5mfSHkD)

Answer (score 9):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 61 bytes

A full program that takes input from STDIN, and outputs to STDOUT.

```c
c;main(d){for(;read(0,&c,1);)putchar(c^d-(d='Xz'%c>0)&32);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcfBCoMwDADQo/6ImoAFncei37GTEJKqg9hIUQaTfXsHe7fHjpXimjP7nV4RBO/FEvgUSKBra2579HhcJ2@UgGdxIGPz/JRFU/HUYT080H9z3oKqvS2pUJR/2CSspssP)

I use the same formula to check for vowels as in [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240487/88546) other task. Here, `(d='Xz'%c>0)` sets `d` equal to \$ 0 \$ if the current letter `c` is a vowel, and \$ 1 \$ otherwise. `c` should be uppercased if and only if  the current `d` is \$ 1 \$, and the previous `d` is \$ 0 \$. To apply the uppercasing, `c` is XOR'ed with \$ 32 \$, but only when the conditions are met. Below is a table to visualize what is happening:

```c
 | prev_d | d | prev_d - d | & 32 | ^ c  |
-+--------+---+------------+------+------+-
 |    0   | 0 |      0     |   0  |   c  |
 |    0   | 1 |     -1     |  32  | 32^c |
 |    1   | 0 |      1     |   0  |   c  |
 |    1   | 1 |      0     |   0  |   c  |
```

Comment: Nice. First answer using C.

Comment: dingledooper, Does `read(0,&c,1)` only work when `int` is little endian?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Probably. If we want to be more inclusive, `~(c=getchar())` works at the cost of a byte.

Comment: I have checked using brute force, that there are [2 byte numbers](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY5BDsIgEEX3nmLSxASautCFMUYPM9BSUDsgUqVepZtu9E7eRrF151-_l__6p-uCtjQMjzaoxebVK-shgiHwSHXFVnm-XPPtDD5D2ENjiMW59SWTmkOCpU50JmSpan04nhpyZ38J11vs7hn_iiKJGP-LWBnbTqBRIHY4vqU5byiwWAAWIPiYOJX-it8) which can be used, but they need to be compared against 2 digit numbers, so you can probably save one byte.

Comment: @Jiří `36865%x>14` is the same length as `'Xz'%c>0`. Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to compress 36865, or any of the other numbers you found.

Comment: @Steffan My idea was to write the number as the multicharacter literal just like it was done in the answer (so it would be 4 chars instead of 5), but I now see that it won't work, because it seems like characters >127 get treated like unicode ones, but maybe it will work with some other compilers.

Answer (score 8):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 56 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/(?<=[aeiou])[^aeiou]/g,x=>x.toUpperCase())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1BDsIwDATvfKS2BO0HCBx4A6cKJDdxQsGKo6TQ/j5U5cZtRzPSPulDxeYxTYeojqs3dTGnpc2chCxDB@ej6YlHfd@wv/9GF/ZbNOk1Jc4XKgyI1WosKtyKBvDQPFhEZ83iKLoN7PoQVHyDuPuLiQbmF7lV1S8)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>30</s> <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```perl
s/[aeiou]\K[^aeiou]/\U$&/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YPzoxNTO/NDbGOzoOwtKPCVVR00///z8jNScnvzy/KCclMS8FzEnOT0lNz89J40pMTEpNzU5M@ZdfUJKZn1f8X7cAAA)

-3 bytes thanks to Sisyphus

-1 byte thanks to Jo King

Comment: Wow, another answer!

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
\zp⁽AḊ⁽ǐẆṅḢ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiXFx6cOKBvUHhuIrigb3HkOG6huG5heG4oiIsIiIsImhlbGxvd29ybGRhbmRoZWxsb2NvZGVnb2xmXG5hYWJlZWthZCJd)

This is a terrible way to do it but it works.

```
\zp⁽AḊ⁽ǐẆṅḢ
\zp         # Prepend "z" so that there is a leading consonant
   ⁽AḊ      # Adjacent-group by is-vowel
      ⁽ǐẆ   # Title-case every second item, starting on the first item
         ṅḢ # Join by nothing and remove the leading "z"
```

Comment: Great, it works. Upvoted! 11 bytes might be hard to beat.

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
`° ß`$‡ǐNøṙ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgwrAgw59gJOKAoceQTsO44bmZIiwiIiwiaGVsbG93b3JsZGFuZGhlbGxvY29kZWdvbGYiXQ==)

An alternate 11 byter that uses regex

See [this golfing tip of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238374/78850) that explains why the string `"° ß"` is `"[aeiou] [bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]"`

### Explained

```
`° ß`$‡ǐNøṙ
`° ß`       # The string `[aeiou] [bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]`
     $      # Make the stack input, ^
      ‡ǐN   # Push a function that title cases a string and then swapscase.
            # This is because regex matches will be vowel-consonant, and title case makes the vowel uppercase, consonant lowercase, swapcase inverts that for the desired result 
         øṙ # Apply that function to regex matches in the input
```

Comment: 11 bytes! Equal best with Steffan!

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 48 bytes

```
\(s)gsub("(?<=[aeiou])([^aeiou])","\\U\\1",s,,T)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3DWI0ijXTi0uTNJQ07G1soxNTM_NLYzU1ouOgLCUdpZiY0JgYQyWdYh2dEE2oPt00DaWM1Jyc_PL8opyUxLwUMCc5PyU1PT8nTUmTCyifmJiUmpqdmKIE1bRgAYQGAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>78</s> <s>66</s> 65 bytes

```python
d=0
for c in input():print(end=[c,c.upper()][d>(d:=c in"aeiou")])
```

Complete program. Thanks to @Neil and @Steffan for making this more concise. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hco9CoAwDEDh3VOIUwsigosI9SLiIE3UQklCaBFPX3/gLR88udPJNIyipYDrq5219nWgN8nJ2Ek0UDJI4Bbf@i6LoBq7LjAbmNy3NhsGzo1dbSknxsgXa4SN4IdnwIPj/gA)

### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 73 bytes (@Steffan)

```python
lambda x:re.sub("(?<=[aeiou])[^aeiou]",lambda a:a[0].upper(),x)
import re
```

Function solution. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpBCsIwEEDRvaco3TSBUgR3xeJBYoWpmdjANDOMCdbTR1B3/8GXd145nWqYrpVgWzw0@6g4PMtiWnM5Tw4wcpmtu/2i7f8bjOCO81BEUI3td3uIm7DmRrGKxpRNMN2KRPxiJQ/Jf3Fnjw@m0FlbPw)

Comment: Great, clever way with python, +1.

Comment: [Regex solution is 73](https://tio.run/##LcpBCsIwEEDRvaco3TSBUgR3xeJBYoWpmdjANDOMCdbTR1B3/8GXd145nWqYrpVgWzw0@6g4PMtiWnM5Tw4wcpmtu/2i7f8bjOCO81BEUI3td3uIm7DmRrGKxpRNMN2KRPxiJQ/Jf3Fnjw@m0FlbPw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYpBCsMgEAC/EnJSCCXQS2mwH5EcxF0bQXaXRQl5vbGFucwwctWD6fkS7R3cunnRTNUggfNxiY8mgmrs7uFj4O3ilGkOmLnNdreJdfqVgbQ6rt4PLIVP1gKB4C@RAb9c0g0 "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @chepner Try It Online hasn't been updated in quite a while and isn't currently maintained, so the latest version of Python it has is 3.8 pre-release. A current alternative is [Attempt This Online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhZoFJQGAA)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: Save another byte by using a for loop instead of list comprehension: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hco9CoAwDEDh3VOIUwsigosI9SLiIE3UQklCaBFPX3/gLR88udPJNIyipYDrq5219nWgN8nJ2Ek0UDJI4Bbf@i6LoBq7LjAbmNy3NhsGzo1dbSknxsgXa4SN4IdnwIPj/gA "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: Not sure about what does and doesn't count as acceptable result, but can't you convert this `print(end=` into `''.join(` and rely on implicit print of the result to get `d=0;''.join([c,c.upper()][d>(d:=c in'aeiou')]for c in input())` for 62 bytes?

Answer (score 5):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>21</s> 16 bytes

```
aRXV.XC;@_.UC_@1
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJhUlhWLlhDO0BfLlVDX0AxIiwiIiwiaGVsbG93b29vcmxkYW5kaGVsbG9jb2RlZ29sZiIsIi1wIl0=)

-5 bytes thanks to @DLosc
Regex solution, ported from [@Steffan's regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255609/110555), with some pip builtin regex patterns used to save bytes

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>21</s> 17 bytes

```
{Iy>YaNVWUC:aa}Ma
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJ7SXk+WWFOVldVQzphYX1NYSIsIiIsImhlbGxvd29vb3JsZGFuZGhlbGxvY29kZWdvbGYiLCIiXQ==)

-4 bytes thanks to @DLosc
Non-regex alternative

Comment: Lookarounds are expensive. Here's a [16-byte](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJhUlhWLlhDO0BfLlVDX0AxIiwiIiwiaGVsbG93b29vcmxkYW5kaGVsbG9jb2RlZ29sZiIsIi1wIl0=) regex solution--not as elegant, but much shorter.

Comment: Here's [17 bytes](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJ7SXk+WWFOVldVQzphYX1NYSIsIiIsImhlbGxvd29vb3JsZGFuZGhlbGxvY29kZWdvbGYiLCIiXQ==) for the non-regex solution (protip: remove the `-p` flag if you don't need list output).

Comment: @DLosc some good tips, cheers

Answer (score 5):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>170</s> 164 bytes

```go
import(."regexp";."strings")
func f(s string)string{return MustCompile(`[aeiou][^aeiou]`).ReplaceAllStringFunc(s,func(x string)string{return x[:1]+ToUpper(x[1:])})}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY_NSsQwFIX3fYqQ1Q1qYXYyrkRwJ4o_q1KZ2N7EMGluyA8WhnkSN0X0IXwU38ZpMwsXrg73cM_HOe8fmqZvL7ut1MgGaVxlBk8h1VwNiX_lpM7Ofz6LBzUPqHH0_KLmMQXjdOSiUtl1TEFkxRJFdgFTDo7d5JiuaPDGImwaiYZy2zwX3Yj6Hr2VHV5a-7DErg8wiKczE8b_iWOzXrUnj_TkPQYYm9W6FXuxP3a9XerMS0CwXXV3SCbrQAF_RWvpjYLtpeuXo6MeNVnFhfj7KOUL4lb2s33ETlPRXw)

No `(?<=)`, non-capturing groups only work with `Find(All)String(Submatch)` which leads to a longer solution, so this mess is what I've had to come with.

- -6 bytes for simplifying the regex.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 30 bytes

```
"aeiou"0>ir[sp<l~!' **lf-ol~>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/18pMTUzv1TJwC6zKLq4wCanTlFdQUsrJ003P6fOLvb//@TE3PzStJzE9NSk/NK8lMSizNRiAA)

This isn't even close to the smallest, but the way it works is probably very different from other languages, so I thought it was worth posting.

It uses two stacks, one with a list of vowels, and one with the STDIN string.  Each character on the STDIN stack is copied to the vowel stack and the code search to see if there's a match.  That "am I a vowel" result is combined with a "was the last char as vowel" result that lives on the stack to decide whether or not to capitalize the current character before printing it.

```
"aeiou"                        - push "is a vowel" comparison data on stack
       0                       - push "0" as "was last char a vowel" starter val
        >i                     - switch to new stack, read STDIN onto it
          r                    - reverse stack
           [                 ] - for each input char/codepoint
            sp<l               - stash the char, delete, switch stacks and restore
                ~!             - search for the char in "aeiou", negate result
                  '            - push " " (32), the "capitalize" codepoint offset
                    *          - multiple to clear if not this IS a vowel
                     *         - multiple against "was previous char vowel?" result 
                      l        - reload the current char/codepoint
                       f-      - flip stack and subtract to capitalize if needed
                         o     - output current char
                          l~   - reload char, search against vowels
                            >  - switch back to the STDIN stack
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Dart (v2.18.4)](https://dartpad.dev/?id=b36328ec7279f5a14f1251485c40aa30), <s>149</s> 80 bytes

```dart
f(s,[d=0])=>String.fromCharCodes([for(s in s.runes)s^d&~(d=68174912>>s%32)&32]);
```

- [Try it online](https://tio.run/##XY/LagJBEEX3@YreRLtBJI4hD2Rm4ydkKQYqXdVa2A@p6saFJL8@mbgK7u69HA5cBKnjGKwudtg/7V0/fFThfFgGKWl7BNkWJLW7UMSq4Wx0KS2TOv3E2Y/F/uVt9fr8vuqGQR/XnZutu73bjAk4W2euD8acJ121wc6PFGO5FIkIGW/FT@5DiWHu3OY/CfBFdAK832MRSnzWlrBMWblConpPZUjQfC0CuRJFSpRrSyC@RfCcGcBTY01/xyrDNLPeHN/jLw).
- [Full source](https://github.com/alexrintt/algorithms/tree/master/codegolf/make-every-consonant-after-a-vowel-uppercase/dart-2.18).

Extra test-cases:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| loremipsumdolorsitamet | loReMiPsuMdoLoRsiTaMeT |
| namauctoranteelementumarculaciniaaceuismodestiaculis | naMauCtoRaNteeLeMeNtuMaRcuLaCiNiaaCeuiSmoDeStiaCuLiS |

---

*Thanks to [@steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan) who cut down to 80 bytes (!) by porting [@arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) answer.*

Comment: I got this down to 104 bytes: `f(s,[v,i=0])=>s.split('').map((e)=>i++<1||!(v='aeiou'.contains)(s[i-2])||v(e)?e:e.toUpperCase()).join();`

Comment: Or 89 by porting AlephSquirrel's answer: `f(s,[d=0])=>s.split('').map((e)=>d>(d='aeiou'.contains(e)?1:0)?e.toUpperCase():e).join();`

Comment: Or 80 by porting Arnauld's answer: `f(s,[d=0])=>String.fromCharCodes([for(s in s.runes)s^d&~(d=68174912>>s%32)&32]);`

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
r"%v%c"ÈÎ+XÌu
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ciIldiVjIsjOK1jMdQ&input=ImhlbGxvd29ybGRhbmRoZWxsb2NvZGVnb2xmIg)

```
r"%v%c"ÈÎ+XÌu     :Implicit input of string
r                 :Replace
 "%v%c"           :RegEx /[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]/gi
       È          :Pass each match through the following function as X
        Î         :  First character
         +        :  Append
          XÌ      :  Last character
            u     :  Uppercased
```

Answer (score 4):

## Vim, 23 keystrokes

```
:s/[aeiou]\+\zs./\u&/g<cr>

:s/                        # Search and replace...
   [aeiou]\+               #    A string of one or more vowels
            \zs            #    (start the match here)
               .           #    Any character
                           #    (because of greedy matching, this will always be the first consonant)
                /          # Replace with
                 \u        #    Make uppercase
                   &       #    The matched string (after \zs)
                    /g<cr> # Replace all occurrences
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 25 bytes

```
T`aeioul`aeiouL`[aeiou]+.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JCExNTO/NAdC@SREg@lYbb3//zNSc3Lyy/OLclIS81LAnOT8lNT0/Jw0rsTEpNTU7MQUAA) Explanation: Transliterates vowels to themselves and other lowercase letters to uppercase letters, but only the letter after a run of vowels. (This is so that a double vowel doesn't confuse the transliteration.)

Alternative, also 25 bytes:

```
rT`aeioul`aeiouL`[aeiou].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@/KCQhMTUzvzQHQvkkRIPpWL3//zNSc3Lyy/OLclIS81LAnOT8lNT0/Jw0rsTEpNTU7MQUAA) Explanation: The `r` makes it match the pattern from right to left solving the double vowel problem.

Both programs work in Retina 1 but 8 bytes can be saved because the `aeiou` can be replaced by `v` in the transliteration patterns.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'zì.γžMså}2Å€™}J¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fverwGr1zm4/u8y0@vLTW6HDro6Y1j1oW1XodWvb/f0ZqTk5@eX5RTkpiXgqYk5yfkpqen5MGAA)

- -4 thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

Port of [Steffan's Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255607/114446)

```
'zì.γžMså}2Å€™}J¦         # Implicit input                           TOP OF THE STACK:
'zì                       # Prepend a 'z'                            "zhelloworldandhellocodegolf"
   .γ    }                # Group by
     žM                   #  The string of vowels                    'aeiou'
       så                 #  Contains the letter                     ["zh", "e", "ll", "o", "w", "o", "rld", "a", "ndh", "e", "ll", "o", "c", "o", "d", "e", "g", "o", "lf"]
          2Å€ }           # Every second item:
             ™            #  Convert to title case                   ["Zh", "e", "Ll", "o", "W", "o", "Rld", "a", "Ndh", "e", "Ll", "o", "C", "o", "D", "e", "G", "o", "Lf"]
               J          # Join everything                          'ZheLloWoRldaNdheLloCoDeGoLf'
                ¦         # And remove the leading 'z'               'heLloWoRldaNdheLloCoDeGoLf'
```

Comment: `š` can be `ì` so the input will remain a string. Then you can change `.å` to `å` and remove the first `J` for -2. In addition, 05AB1E has an _every b'th_ builtin (`Å€`), so `ā<ÈÅÏ™}` can be `2Å€™}` for another -2. [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fverwGr1zm4/u8y0@vLTW6HDro6Y1j1oW1XodWvb/f0ZqTk5@eX5RTkpiXgqYk5yfkpqen5MGAA)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 48 bytes

```c
d;f(*s){for(d=1;*s;)*s++^=d-(d='Xz'%*s>0)&32;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtbCsIwFEQ/tVlFCNQmqQUfnyGuwAUIohDyqIWYSG5AsHTtsUrnb86c0Z32KvSlGOEoBza6mKiRe8FBMA5te5emm0Fz@axXTc3htGOb40FM5amGQBkaUTWEjLOFfL1hic/kYb2P75i8UcH8i47G9tE7IlDl6E9lAuElrzT/HSW1B7LFyziVLw)

[dingledooper's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255612/41374) as a function.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
⭆θ⎇№⌕Ａ⭆θ№aeiouλ10⊖κ↥ιι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYoxCkIxEAWvElJlIYLWVqLYCYJ6gCVZ/w@u2bjmK54@Rq2shnnzwogaBLm1vaZc3aF2DDss7ubNkTSjvtxapp62KccV8//llyxSksl6wwDe2MXcdmwoKF0pV4ru8tlPpZAGvJNL3RIALFsbiVmeohwxx68EiTQIn9vswW8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Maps each letter to its vowel-ness as a binary flag, then searches for the substring `10` in the result, the second character of which is where the consonants that needs to be uppercased are.

```
 θ                      Input string
⭆                       Map over letters and join
   №                    Count of
                  κ     Current index
                 ⊖      Decremented
       θ                In input string
      ⭆                 Map over letters and join
        №               Count of
              λ         Inner letter in
         aeiou          Literal string `aeiou`
    ⌕Ａ                  Find all matches of
               10       Literal string `10`
  ⎇                     If found then
                    ι   Current consonant
                   ↥    Uppercased
                     ι  Else current letter
                        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 25 bytes

```
s/[aeiou][^aeiou]/\U\l&/g
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlwYKlpSVpuhY7i_WjE1Mz80tjo-MgtH5MaEyOmn46RB6qbMFN5YzUnJz88vyinJTEvBQwJzk_JTU9PyeNKzExKTU1OzEFohYA)

It makes the whole match uppercase and then it turns first letter to lowercase. This is 5 bytes shorter than `s/([aeiou])([^aeiou])/\1\u\2/g` solution and it also doesn't require `-E` flag.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 23 bytes

```
(?<=[aeiou])[^aeiou]
$u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X8PexjY6MTUzvzRWMzoOwuBSKf3/PzExKTU1OzEFAA)

`$u` is replace with uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Œue€ØḄ<ƝŻTƲ¦
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of lowercase characters and yields a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opNLUR01rDs94uKPF5tjco7tDjm06tOz///9JSYlJiUCUBCJBBBgkJQEA)**

#### How?

```
Œue€ØḄ<ƝŻTƲ¦ - Link: list of lowercase characters, S
           ¦ - sparse application (to S)...
          Ʋ  - ...to indices: last four links as a monad - f(S):
    ØḄ       -     lowercase consonants
   €         -       for each (character in S):
  e          -         exists in? -> 1 if a consonant else 0
       Ɲ     -     for neighbours:
      <      -       less than? -> 1 if [0,1] else 0
        Ż    -     prepend a zero
         T   -     truthy indices -> indices of consonants directly after a vowel
Œu           - ...action: convert to uppercase
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/) `--extendedglob`, 52 bytes

```fortran
<<<${1//(#m)[aeiou][^aeiou]/$MATCH[1]${(U)MATCH[2]}}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxDoIwFEV3v4JEhnYiOLMYFxc3nQgmj/YBjW0foa/RSPj22sh0z70nud8wpUFIEZBp5gI/jF6jHi31qWmacq2rShydbAENxa597lmVt/P9cm3rrlzFQ@7l1G1bkoehmNBaetNiNXj9L4o0jmSHLAF6xBfojJYWdGYO0WnKHAyDQ87Cg4OomBbwjGjRoefoYFHRgjLeACiMJrj8GthAnk1IPw)   <sub><s>[69 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYy9CsIwFIV3n6Jgh3Yq7l2KCAqKi52Kwm1yW4NJbmluUCx59hpap/PzHc7XPecuyzOHTAMn@GG0EmWvqZ3LskyndNoVRbY1eQOoyN@bx6pFOmV1fqlu@2MI/0V1OF3rhZxXUoQw55sueaLW9KZRS7ByCYIk9qS7CAFaxBfIaDWNaNTgvJEUvVMMBjkCCwa8YBrBMqJGg5a9gVF4DUJZBSDQK2fiq2MFsVZu/gE)</s></sub>

Hat-tips: [one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254319/15940) [two](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248255/15940)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 51 bytes

```
[ R/ [aeiou][^aeiou]/ [ "\0 "v- ] re-replace-with ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY69DoJAGAR7nmJjD1rrAxgbC40VYvJxt/zEgzuOAzTGZ0fUarKzzRSigvXz5Xw47rfwLPlwaCRUycjv08N5hvB0vm4DenYDW8Ue3YRdFHXTCxWNsZP1Rkurf0NZzdKaAiI5eRcNyZUmAqVZnFJ4zylOa6TC2g5ZevtzEVhdN1iNMbKlJfZ0RhTjqQ4VsrkRh2T@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 90 bytes

```python
lambda x:"".join(b.upper()if a in"aeiou"and b not in"aeiou"else b for a,b in zip(" "+x,x))
```

Would be 71 bytes if didn't have to deal with repetitive vowels, still got 90 bytes though. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcwxDsIwDIXhnVNYXpqIqgsbEjdhcRqHBkwchVQULh8iBhjfp6c/v@qi6dDC6dyE7s4TbEfE6aoxGTetOXMxNgYgiAmJo65IyYODpPVPLA/uFrQAja47vGM2CLjfxs3alktM1QQzLCyiTy3ie@U7ZvV8UQmDtbvfjcgx38h3bB8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 26 bytes

```
{S:g[<[aeiou]>+<(.]=$/.uc}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OtgqPdomOjE1M7801k7bRkMv1lZFX680ufZ/cWKlgpJKvIKtnUJ1moJKfK2SQlp@kYJ6RmpOTn55flFOSmJeCpiTnJ@Smp6fk6auo6CemJiUmpqdmKL@HwA)

Comment: How does this work? Could you write an explanation please?

Comment: @south It substitutes (`S`) each occurrence (globally, `:g`) in the input string of one or more vowels (`<[aeiou]>+`) followed by any character (`.`) by the matched text (`$/`) converted to uppercase (`.uc`).  Or rather it would do that if not for the capture marker (`<(`) which causes the matched text to include _only_ the single character following the vowels, so that's the only character that gets replaced with its uppercase version.  The opening capture marker `<(` can be paired with a closing marker `)>`, but it's unnecessary here since the matched text extends to the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, 36 bytes

```ruby
gsub /(?<=[aeiou])[^aeiou]/,&:upcase
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclm0km6BUuyCpaUlaboWN1XSi0uTFPQ17G1soxNTM_NLYzWj4yAMfR01q9KC5MTiVIhaqJYFN5UzUnNy8svzi3JSEvNSwJzk_JTU9PycNK7ExKTU1OzEFIhaAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 19 bytes

```
sm?*Z!=Z}d"aeiou"r1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzjXXitK0TaqNkUpMTUzv1SpyPD/f6WM1Jyc/PL8opyUxLwUMCc5PyU1PT8nTQkA)

#### Explanation

```
sm?*Z!=Z}d"aeiou"r1ddQ    # implicitly add ddQ to the end
                          # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
s                         # sum of
 m                   Q    # map lambda d over Q
  ?                       # ternary if (
   *Z!                    # Z and not
      =Z}d"aeiou"         # assign Z to d being a vowel):
                 r1d      #   d capitalized
                    d     # else: d
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby 2.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 110 bytes

```ruby
->(s){v="aeiou";s.chars.map.with_index{v.include?(s[_2-1])&&!v.include?(_1)?(_1.upcase):_1}.join}
```